# What is the correct regular expression for an email address?

Tags: regex, email

**Duplicate**: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

---

There seem to be an awful lot of different variants on this on the web and was wondering if there is a definitive answer?

Preferably using the .net (Regex) dialect of regular expressions.

Comment: Please see that one [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question has been ***asked* and *answered*** several times:

[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

[Why are people using regexp for email and other complex validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211842/why-are-people-using-regexp-for-email-and-other-complex-validation)

[Regexp recognition of email address hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard)

**Specifically related to .NET:**

[Validating e-mail with regular expression VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369543/validating-e-mail-with-regular-expression-vb-net)

Comment: All here: HTTP://EMAILREGEX.COM

Answer (score 1):

[regular-expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) says that this one matches about 99%

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Comment: I hate that linked page, and the authors idea of what acceptable trade-offs are. That is one of the better versions of the regex he lists though.

Answer (score 1):

The *definitive* answer? Or the *normal* answer?

I ask because the **formal** email address specification allows all sorts of weird things (parenthesis, quoted phrases, etc) that most people don't bother to account for.

See [this page](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx) for a list of both *comprehensive* and *normal* regex'es.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t think there´s a silver bullet for email regex verification.

what people are commonly doing is to verify only for mistakes, like the absence of @ and one dot. And then send a email verification to that address. It´s the only way to be sure that they email is actually valid.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem some time ago. [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1) defines it and according to [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) this one is useful and is the one i picked: "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:a-z0-9?.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum)\b"

Comment: why would that required the tld's inside it? what about .ca and .uk for instance?

Comment: Also, .asia. Trying to ensure the domain is valid inside of a regex is an exercise in futility and not what a regex is meant to do. A regex should only ensure it is in a valid format.

Comment: Those are only good for matching *US* addresses. While you're at it, you should just ping the domain and check it's valid. Then you don't have to make a regex that contains every suffix imaginable.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Probably want to add A-Z next to all the lower case versions in order to allow uppercase letters as well.

Comment: or just use it in case-insensitive mode

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's one definitive answer for this one, but if you put aside actually checking if the domain exists, email addresses boil down to `<username>@<domain>`, where `<domain>` contains at least one dot and two to four characters in the suffix. You can do all kinds of things to check for illegal/special characters, but the simplest one would be:

```
^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$
```

Comment: Why `[\w-\.]+`?