# regex to get emailaddress with / without display name

Tags: regex, email-address

In my case, content will come it may contain emailaddress in any of the below format.

```
1. From : dr-dscsda-ds-info@asdf.com
2. From:sadaedf@sdc.sdfds
3. rom: sdcasdc <information@dsf.net> 
4. From: "adads" <adsasd@adsc.cd>
5. From: <customercare@ddsaf.com>
```

I need to find the one of the above pattern and extract the email address from this

Regex I tried

```
From\s*:\s*((["|']?)[\w|\s]+\2)?\s*(\<?)([\w]([\w\-\.\+\'\/]*)@([\w\-\.]*)(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,22}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2}){0,2}))(\>?)
```

All the format matches in my regex. But except 1 and 2, I'll be extract the email address from the regex using group(4).

But in case of 1 and 2, It does not give me full emailaddress.

Please help to alter the regex so that it matches all my case.

Comment: You’ve got so many capturing groups… use `(?:`…`)` more often. Use `(`…`)` only when needed, e.g. to extract the email itself. It’s getting quite confusing otherwise.

Comment: [`From\s*:\s*.*?([^"\n<>]+@[^"\n<>]+\.[^"\n<>]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/L4TdiL/1) appears to work just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct regular expression for an email address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450696/what-is-the-correct-regular-expression-for-an-email-address)

Comment: @Xufox "Appears to work" until you add more test cases, yes. This is a common FAQ and the standard answer is "don't do that; or at least understand the problem well enough to understand what compromises you need to make".  Not using a regex is usually the sane way forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex expects an unquoted name before the actual email address. It’s already matching some letters without knowing whether they belong to the email address or to the unquoted name.

I think your regex may be a bit too complex; it can be simplified. This regex appears to work just fine for those cases:

```
/From\s*:\s*.*?([^"'<>\s]+@[^"<>\s]+\.[^"'<>\s]+)/gi
```

[RegEx101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L4TdiL/2).

The first capturing group gives you the email address.

It tries to match characters before and after an `@` symbol that don’t include spaces or other delimiters. After the `@` a TLD has to appear.

This can’t filter out *all* invalid emails or match *all* valid emails, but it’s good enough for most cases.