# Ruby Regular Expression Excluding

Tags: ruby, regex

```
@message_to = 'bob@google.com'

@cleaned = @message_to.match(/^(.*)+@/)
```

@cleaned is returning bob@, where I want it to return just bob. Am I doing the regex right with ruby?

Thanks

Comment: I think regex and email addresses are some sort of gateway-drug-combination for developers. This is a worthy SO question and discussion about the pair: [Why are people using regexp for email and other complex validation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211842/why-are-people-using-regexp-for-email-and-other-complex-validation)

Comment: @the Tin Man: All programmers are really failed wizards that would rather be casting spells, regular expressions smell like incantations so there's a natural affinity for them.

Comment: @mu is too short, LOL. Yes, very possibly. I always thought it was a macho thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
@cleaned = @message_to.match(/^(.*)+@/)[1]
```

[`match`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001235) returns a [`MatchData`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html) object and the string version of that is the entire match, the captured groups are available starting at index 1 when you treat the `MatchData` [as an array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html#M000407).

I'd probably go with something more like this though:

```
@cleaned = @message_to.match(/^([^@]+)@/)[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

No need much regular expression

```
>> @message_to = "bob@google.com"
=> "bob@google.com"
>> @message_to.split("@",2)
=> ["bob", "google.com"]
>> @message_to.split("@",2)[0] if @message_to["@"]
=> "bob"
>>
```

Comment: +1: People do tend to get fixated on using regexes for everything, basic string mangling shouldn't be overlooked.

Comment: +1 It's the old "when you have a hammer everything looks like a nail." situation. Regex is a powerful tool, but I find it usually contributes to confusing code, rather than making it clearer, cleaner, and more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

An even shorter code than mu_is_too_short would be:

```
@cleaned = @message_to[/^([^@]+)@/, 1]
```

The [String#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001128) method can take a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

There is a shorter solution:

```
@cleaned = @message_to[/[^@]+/]
```

Answer (score 0):

The **simplest** RegEx I got to work in the IRB console is:

```
@message_to = 'bob@google.com'
@cleaned = @message_to.match(/(.+)@/)[1]
```

Also from this [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3alX1OaNhFJb8J%3asocial.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/regexp/thread/4e35e77b-73c5-4d19-9427-e81b3f75d1f5+local-part+email+address+regex&cd=21&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com) you could try:

```
@cleaned = @message_to.match(/^(?<local_part>[\w\W]*?)@/)[:local_part]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to adjust your code is by using a forward positive assertion. Instead of saying "match `bob@`" you're now saying "match `bob`, when followed by a `@`"

```
@message_to = 'bob@google.com'

@cleaned = @message_to.match(/^(.*)+(?=@)/)
```

A further point about when to use and not to use regexes: yes, using a regex is a bit pointless in this case. But when you do use a regex, it's easier to add validation as well:

```
@cleaned = @message_to.match(/^(([-a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~]+.)*[-a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~]+(?=@)/)
```

(and yes, all those are valid in email-adresses)

Comment: "But when you do use a regex, it's easier to add validation as well", except those don't really cover all the corner cases for email addresses, or test whether it's a live address, which is the real-world test. Perl's [Mail::RFC822::Address](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PDWARREN/Mail-RFC822-Address-0.3/Address.pm) module has the `make_rfc822re` function which takes a pretty good shot at generating a RFC-compliant [regex](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). This is a pertinent discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/q/211842/128421