# Email entry regex validation

Tags: c#, regex, validation, email

I am using the following regex to validate an email address:

```
"^[-a-zA-Z0-9][-.a-zA-Z0-9]*@[-.a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[-.a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.(com|edu|info|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|name|museum|coop|aero|pro|[a-zA-Z]{2})$"
```

Unfortunately, this does not allow email addresses with <strike>hyphens</strike> underscores. Ex.:

> first_last@abc.com

How can I modify this to allow <strike>hyphens</strike> underscores?

Comment: Do you mean underscores as in: _ ?  Hyphens are -, well technically my writer wife tells me that there is difference between a dash - and a hyphen - but I'll be damned if I learn what it is.

Comment: Yes, I meant underscore.  It is too early in the morning for me to be working with regexes.  :)  Thanks for catching my mistake!

Comment: The difference between hyphens, dashes, minusses, etc pp is annoying enough for them to form their own unicode character class: "Punctuation Dash"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_` is not hyphen, it is underscore. Hyphen is `-`

If it is okay to start an email address with an underscore, add `_` to both of the character classes that appear before `@`

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9_][-.a-zA-Z0-9_]*@...
```

If the email id cannot start with an `_`, add it only to the second character class:

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9][-.a-zA-Z0-9_]*@...
```

---

That said, your regex has a couple of issues:

1. It accepts email addresses starting with a hyphen; is this intended? If not, remove the `-` from the first character class to make it `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
2. It accepts consecutive periods after the first character thereby making `3...@example.com` a valid id - is this *status-by-design*?

RFC specification for email address is quite complicated. See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210945/what-would-be-a-globally-accepted-regular-expression-to-match-e-mail-addresses) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses) for more information. Also don't forget to check the one and only [perfect and the official regex](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) for validating email addresses (be warned that you might find it a **little** longer than what sanity would suggest)

Comment: There is no perfect regexpr because emails can't be described with a regular grammer - they need a context sensitive grammer.

Comment: You could also try using http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt to validate email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

```
"^[-_a-zA-Z0-9][-_.a-zA-Z0-9]*@[-_.a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[_-.a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.(com|edu|info|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|name|museum|coop|aero|pro|[a-zA-Z]{2})$"
```

Possibly?

Answer (score 1):

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9_][-.a-zA-Z0-9_]*@[-.a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[-.a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.(com|edu|info|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|name|museum|coop|aero|pro|[a-zA-Z]{2})$
```

I added "_" to your two character classes.

Answer (score 1):

Regular-expressions.info has a very good discussion of [e-mail address validation by regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), including his preferred regex for "99% of all e-mail addresses in use today", and another to match e-mail addresses as defined by RFC-2822.

I won't do the author a disservice by copying his work here.  But I do think it's worthy of a read since it's directly related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an interesting blog [post about email validation](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2005/01/10/350135.aspx) on Larry Osterman's website.

This is a followup post to the original post in which he attempts to generate a regular expression to validate an email address. His RegExp is:

```
string strRegex = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                  @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" + 
                  @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";
```

His notes:

> The key thing to note in this grammar is that the local-part is almost free-form when it comes to the local part.  And there are characters allowed in the local part like !, *, $, etc that are totally legal according to RFC2822 that aren't allowed.

and ...

> Adi Oltean pointed out that V2 of the .Net framework contains the System.Net.MailAddress class which contains a built-in validator.

It looks like the System.Net.Mail.MailAddress constructor validates email addresses and you can catch a FormatException to ensure that the email is valid.