# Looking for a regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I need a regex which match in all cases the associate email address of the from 'tag'.

Examples:

```
From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?First_Second_=28Company_Inc=29?=
    <first.second@email.com>

From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?First_Second_=28Company_Inc=29?=
 <first.second@email.com>

From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?First_Second_=28Company_Inc=29?=
 first.second@email.com

From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?First_Second_=28Company_Inc=29?=
    first.second@email.com

From: first.second@email.com

From: <first.second@email.com>
```

I tried different patterns (RegexOptions.Multiline) but probably took a false approach. The one listed below matches not to the second to last.

```
^From: ([^<>\r\n]+([ |\r\n|\r|\n][\t| ])?)?[<]?([^<>]+)[>]?$
```

Thanks in advance.

Kinde regards,
Danny

Comment: Do you want to match everything after the `From: `, or just the email address `first.second@email.com`?

Comment: just the email address. if it's easier to match the whole part (including the </>) then it's also an acceptable solution (calling trim() will do the job).

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/210945/589206 for a complete answer! :)

Comment: these lines are snippets of a complete email header. i don't need to validate whether the email address is correct or not. i need the sender address of an email. searching for valid email address in a email header will result in countless matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further try and error I got the pattern

```
From:( [^<>\r\n]+[ |\r\n|\r|\n]?)?[\t| ]+[<]?([^<>]+?@[^>\r\n]+)[>]?
```