# How to field validate in visual basic

Tags: regex, vb.net, validation, email-validation

Say i'm creating an email list. How would I validate the field to not accept text without the '@' sign?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710505/asp-net-email-validator-regex/1710535#1710535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check indexOf() method. It will return an integer.

```
If email.indexOf("@") < 3 Then
MessageBox("Invalid email")
End If
```

I think this syntax is correct. Not sure ;)

Comment: `IndexOf` returns the zero-based position of the string that is found, or -1 if it is not. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: I added 3 because he want to validate Email address.

Comment: But the name portion of an email address can be as short as one character. My email address could be `c@codygray.com`. That would fail your test here.

Comment: Hmm thats true. But I thought min 3 characters required before @ symbol.

Comment: Sorry about the insufficient amount of description. I'm a newbie at vb, and I was making an address book in which if the email did not contain "@", a message box would appear saying "Invalid Email". I found out that I needed the Contains or IndexOf Strings.