# Using multiple forms, submit buttons on an ASP.NET web forms page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

[image]

I have 3 different submit buttons(Log In, Search, Insert) in the same page and what I want is to find the best way to have this 3 buttons doing a different things when I press them, or I press enter while I am about to press them.
As you can see from my photo, when I press `Log In` the Insert is pressed too because I have a `global form` in my Master Page.

I tried to use different forms, but i can't because I need them to have `runat="server"`, which is not possible for a page to have.

I use asp Texboxes:

```
<asp:TextBox class="text-input" ID="txtLoginEmail" runat="server"
Height="15px" Width="130px"></asp:TextBox>
```

and asp Buttons:

```
<asp:Button class="submit google-button" ID="btnLogin" onclick="btnLogin_Click" 

runat="server" Text="Log in" />
```

except my Search button which is linkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="searchLink" runat="server" onclick="searchLink_Click">Search</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Check which of them made the postback. (the sender parameter). Besides that, take a look at Model View Presenter. It's a good way to work with webforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [Validation Groups](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2004/10/24/246945.aspx) to cause only required text boxes validation on specific button click. And then in event handler to concrete button you may execute specific logic.

Comment: You could use `CausesValidation=false` in most similar situations, but here it seems that each button does have it's own set of validations, so groups is indeed the correct solution.

Comment: I need more than that, I need also length check and equalsTo check(for the confirm password).

Comment: You may check string length with RegularExpressionValidator (e.g ^[\w\s]{1,50}$). For equals you may use CompareValidator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx)

Comment: One more thing, how can I check for the email, if it is valid.

Comment: Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710505/asp-net-email-validator-regex