# ASP.NET compare validator for matching 2 email addresses

Tags: asp.net

I want to validate 2 fields using compare validator
1)Email address (required field - used required field validator)
2)Confirm email address

If I enter abc@abc.com in email address AND abc@abc.com in confirm email address, it will work fine.
But when I add space after the email address in one of the textbox, it will say that both emails do not match which is not desirable.
How to solve this ? 
It would be helpful for the user if I would be able to notify to the user that the space is not allowed in email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if a user adds a space the emails do not match so the error message is correct. If you want to add another validation for allowed characters you could use a `RegularExpressionValidator` on each field. Here's an example with [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710535/848330):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
     id="RegValid" 
     ControlToValidate="txtEmail" 
     ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
     ErrorMessage="Invalid email address"
     runat="server" >
</asp: RegularExpressionValidator>
```

---

Looks like you need more complex validations so you could probably replace everything with a custom validator and test everything. Markup:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" OnServerValidate="EmailValidate" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtEmail2" ID="vldEmail"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void EmailValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if(txtEmail1.Text != txtEmail2.Text) {
        args.IsValid = False
        vldEmail.ErrorMessage = "Emails are different"
    }else {
        //for each condition that fails set IsValid to false and choose the error message:
        args.IsValid = False
        vldEmail.ErrorMessage = "..."
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I agree with that, in this case I give "Invalid email address" as the error message, but I want to give "No Space allowed" when the space is entered by the user and for all other case "Invalid Email address". Any solution?

Comment: @Warrior You could ad another validator with `ValidationExpression="[^\s]+"`

Comment: yeah, the trouble I am facing with that is 2 error messages are getting displayed

Comment: @Warrior maybe a custom validator is simpler in this case. see my updated anwer

Answer (score 0):

```
regex = '^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[\S]*$'
```

[Source](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?754687-regex-to-allow-anything-but-whitespace)

tried it myself works fine :)