# email validation by user confirmation email in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email-validation, email-confirmation

i was wonder if anyone have or could show me any tutorial on user confirmation email on registration? i've been looking for it for quite some times but no luck with a working one?

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: we are not here to teach you something please post some code and we will fix it

Comment: You could generate a random hash key and send that as a link in an email, and have a page that takes the hash keys as a parameter.. link it up to the email you sent it to and you're verified. But absolutely post code first.

Comment: Refer this link it is helpful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710505/asp-net-email-validator-regex

Answer (score 1):

I can only tell you the steps involved in sending email confirmation 

1) create database table and add columns you required ie firstname, lastname,VerificationCode, Dob ,active etc for registration

2) create a Registration form and add textboxes against you table 

3) on saving form in databse generate Verification code save it in database and in email function 

4) Send Email with verification code which was generated as querystring encrypted

5) In login page get verification code and decrypt it and verify with database

6) If verified then redirect the user to login page or else show exception

let me know if you have any questions

Comment: or instead step (5) you can send in the email link that will redirect to activation page that will activate automatically this account