# How to use Beautiful Soup to extract string in <script> tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In a given .html page, I have a script tag like so:

```
     <script>jQuery(window).load(function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery("input[name=Email]").val("name@email.com");
  }, 1000);
});</script>
```

How can I use Beautiful Soup to extract the email address?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To add a bit more to the [@Bob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547945/771848) and assuming you need to also locate the `script` tag in the HTML which may have other `script` tags.

The idea is to define a regular expression that would be used for both [locating the element with `BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) and extracting the `email` value:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<body>
    <script>jQuery(window).load(function () {
      setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery("input[name=Email]").val("name@email.com");
      }, 1000);
    });</script>
</body>
"""
pattern = re.compile(r'\.val\("([^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+)"\);', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
if script:
    match = pattern.search(script.text)
    if match:
        email = match.group(1)
        print(email)
```

Prints: `name@email.com`.

Here we are using a [simple regular expression for the email address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742588/771848), but we can go further and be more strict about it but I doubt that would be practically necessary for this problem.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into a similar problem and the issue seems to be that calling `script_tag.text` returns an empty string. Instead, you have to call `script_tag.string`. Maybe this changed in some version of BeautifulSoup?

Anyway, [@alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38549684/426794) didn't work for me, so I modified their solution:

```py
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<body>
    <script>jQuery(window).load(function () {
      setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery("input[name=Email]").val("name@email.com");
      }, 1000);
    });</script>
</body>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

script_tag = soup.find("script")
if script_tag:
  # contains all of the script tag, e.g. "jQuery(window)..."
  script_tag_contents = script_tag.string

  # from there you can search the string using a regex, etc.
  email = re.search(r'\.+val\("(.+)"\);', script_tag_contents).group(1)
  print(email)
```

This prints `name@email.com`.

Comment: I got the same issue, thanks man, you saved my life!

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `string`! This must have changed in version 4.9.0. Changelog: "Embedded CSS and Javascript is now stored in distinct Stylesheet and Script tags, which are ignored by methods like get_text() since most people don't consider this sort of content to be 'text'."

Answer (score 3):

not possible using only BeautifulSoup, but you can do it for example with BS + regular expressions

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = """<script> ... </script>"""

bs = BS(html)

txt = bs.script.get_text()

email = re.match(r'.+val\("(.+?)"\);', txt).group(1)
```

or like this:

```
...

email = txt.split('.val("')[1].split('");')[0]
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, indeed txt is an empty string now.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the string inside the `<script>` tag, you can use `.contents` or `.string`.

```
data = """
   <body>
<script>jQuery(window).load(function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery("input[name=Email]").val("name@email.com");
  }, 1000);
});</script>
 </body>
    """
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

script = soup.find("script")
inner_text_with_string = script.string
inner_text_with_content = script.contents[0]

print('inner_text_with_string', inner_text_with_string)
print('inner_text_with_content', inner_text_with_content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this with just a couple of lines of [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho) and `.split`, no regex required!

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

html = """\
<script>jQuery(window).load(function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery("input[name=Email]").val("name@email.com");
  }, 1000);
});</script>
"""

soup = Soup(html)
string = soup.find("script").text
string.split(".val(\"")[-1].split("\");")[0]
```

Which would output:

```py
'name@email.com'
```