# How do I scrape text from <script> tags with bs4?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape some text from a  tag with BS4, but I keep getting a TypeError every time I run my script.

I have tried using a couple different parsers but they all return the same TypeError.

My python code is:

```
s = requests.Session()
r = (s.get(url, headers=headers))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
profile = soup.find('script', attrs={'name': 'window.profile'})['value']
```

The HTML I want to scrape is:

```
<script>
// Profile helper.
window.profile = 'PROFILEIDHERE';
</script>
```

The expected result of my code was to assign the value of 'window.profile' to the variable 'profile', but I am getting a TypeError every time I run my script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Beautiful Soup to extract string in <script> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547569/how-to-use-beautiful-soup-to-extract-string-in-script-tag)

Answer (score 0):

you can use get_text() to get the text value of a tag :

```
allScripts = soup.find_all("script")
for script in allScripts:
    scriptText = script.get_text()
    scriptTextValue = scriptText.split("'")[1]
    print(scriptTextValue)
```