# Find string, extract value

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse HTML in `Python` that has an inline script in it. I need to find a string inside of the script, then extract the value. I've been trying to do this in `regex` for the past few hours, but I'm still not convinced this is the correct approach.

Here is a sample:

```
['key_to_search_for']['post_date'] = '10 days ago';
```

The result I want to extract is: `10 days ago`

This regex gets me part of the way, but I can't figure out the full match:

```
^\[\'key_to_search_for\'\]\[\'post_date\'\] = '(\d{1,2})+( \w)
```

[Regex playground](http://regexr.com/4jdkv)

However, even once I can match with `regex`, I'm not sure the best way to get only the value. I was thinking of just replacing the keys with blanks, like .replace('['key_to_search_for']['post_date'] = '',''), but that seems inefficient.

Should I be matching the `regex` then replacing? Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: parsing html with regex is wrong, but show more context, show html context - cause now it seems to be just a regular string and that could be "regexed"

Comment: You can extract the value using a single capturing group `^\['key_to_search_for'\]\['post_date'\] = '(\d{1,2} \w+ \w+)';$`  See https://regex101.com/r/ee60zU/1

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm using beautiful soup to parse the HTML, but beautiful soup doesn't handle inline scripts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547569/how-to-use-beautiful-soup-to-extract-string-in-script-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the value using a single capturing group and match the 2 words using a quantifier for `\w+`.

The value is in capture group 1.

```
^\['key_to_search_for'\]\['post_date'\] = '(\d{1,2} \w+ \w+)';$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ee60zU/1)

Or use a negated character class matching any char except a `'`

```
^\['key_to_search_for'\]\['post_date'\] = '([^']+)';$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ee60zU/2)