# Find data from Script tag in BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm building a webscraper but got stuck in one problem. How to get that data value?

```
<script>
                var store = {
                        data: 'ffggel4784hth4ve8bf5hhe8rh4b1d4g84usd9',
                        domain: 'www.domain.com'
                };
</script>
```

I'm using python with requests and bs4.

```
x = Beautifulsoup.find('script')
data = x.text
```

I got output

```
                var store = {
                        data: 'ffggel4784hth4ve8bf5hhe8rh4b1d4g84usd9',
                        domain: 'www.domain.com'
                };
```

Now how to get that data value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Beautiful Soup to extract string in <script> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547569/how-to-use-beautiful-soup-to-extract-string-in-script-tag)

Comment: it is normal string so split it into lines - `split('\n")` and split on `:` or slice using `[start:end]`. You can also use `regex`

Answer (score 0):

It is normal string so use string's functions like `strip()`, `split()`, `replace()`, slicing

For example

```
text = '''var store = {
                        data: 'ffggel4784hth4ve8bf5hhe8rh4b1d4g84usd9',
                        domain: 'www.domain.com'
                };'''

lines = text.split('\n')

parts = lines[1].strip().split(': ')
name = parts[0]
data = parts[1].strip(',')[1:-1]
print(name, '=', data)

parts = lines[2].strip().split(': ')
name = parts[0]
data = parts[1].strip(',')[1:-1]
print(name, '=', data)
```

Result

```
data = ffggel4784hth4ve8bf5hhe8rh4b1d4g84usd9
domain = www.domain.com
```