# Python | BS4 How to extract script from <script></script>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Easy question, I know many of you are a lot better than me.
How do I extract json code out of it, so I can work with bs4 on it. In python. Thank you, please don't downgrade:)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"kkEzPAyLVqXzZaS3xITIlWtkCF6tUi2m","viewer":null,"viewerId":null},"country_code":"PL","language_code":"pl","locale":"pl_PL","entry_data":{"ProfilePage":[{"logging_page_id"..."version":"10"},"is_dev":false,"rollout_hash":"fd856a1a782f","bundle_variant":"es6","frontend_env":"prod"};</script>
```

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547569/how-to-use-beautiful-soup-to-extract-string-in-script-tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Beautiful Soup to extract string in <script> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547569/how-to-use-beautiful-soup-to-extract-string-in-script-tag)

Comment: Can you share URL or post full content of `<script>` element? Current `<script>` element contains invalid Json - you probably shortened it.

Comment: yes, original content is too long, it's basically json database

Comment: everything I need to do is delete: " <script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {" and ";</script>"

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can do it this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

element = soup.Find("script", type = "text/javascript")
json = element.get("window._sharedData")
```

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5zOv3D here is my code with your correction, but it results with None

Comment: https://codeshare.io/29gQQX here is the result I want to change

Comment: janson = json.loads('{'+page.text.split('{',1)[1].rsplit(';',1)[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I've edited it a little bit and added page = str(page) and removed .text. Now it's working well, thanks