# Laravel Email Validation letting "user@hotmail" through

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel's Validation through FormRequest. An extract of the code is here. It seems laravel's validation is letting email addresses like "user@hotmail" through.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class DirectorForm extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
    }
}
```

it seems the above validation allows "username@hotmail", which isn't a valid email address.

Did i set it up wrongly

Comment: that is a valid email address format. a regex can only do so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex from: https://emailregex.com/

And combine with Laravel regex rule: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-regex

Answer (score 2):

Actually `user@hotmail` is a valid email, as `user@localhost` can also be a valid email address.
If you want to check that if the email address also contains a [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), you can try:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class DirectorForm extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|regex:.+@.+\..+',
        ];
    }
}
```

For more regex email validation rules take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742588/2953830).

Answer (score 0):

It appears validation is working as expected. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom validation for an email in `AppServiceProvider` like

**Boot** method

```
Validator::extend('email_address', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return (!preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $value)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        });
```

`Rules`

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email_address',
        ];
    }
```