# Email Regular Expression Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created the following regular expression for validating my email

```
^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-]+$
```

Now the issue that I am facing with the expression is an email of the following format is also being accepted

```
abc_xyz@gmail
```

I want the regular expression to enforce that the email address should contain the `".com/info/net"` at the end , and that the above mentioned email format should be marked as invalid.

how can i achieve this

Comment: In fact, Google can already apply for a "gmail" top level domain. It's pretty expensive but it can be done :)

Comment: You don't need to reinvent the wheel; there are plenty of examples and discussions on the web about email regexp's.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario
Yea.. considering they got the money. :)

But in my case i would like to enforce the `.com` at the end, how can i achieve that

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP email validation question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514810/php-email-validation-question). The question talks about PHP but the accepted answer is quite language agnostic.

Comment: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses

Comment: You're also disallowing upper-case letters. Also, that regex does not actually accept the string you say it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Regular Expression Email Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940577/javascript-regular-expression-email-validation)

Comment: this is not a duplicate as he wishes to constrain the domains and none of those questions answer that

Comment: @ori
well, i thought of posting a domain specific question as that might be helpful to others who want to implement it.

Comment: @Pointy
Yes, i overlooked that one. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Why are you trying to limit the tld's?  What about .me, .us, .gov, .name, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|info)$
```

Try that. You can add as many other domain restraints as you wish. Just separate them with |

You may wish to take a look at this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for more info   on regex, and http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for specific help on emails.

Comment: Thanks... I'll have a look at the sites that you have mentioned to understand the regular expression that you have built :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape - inside your character classes, but still that email address should fail.

try:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._%\-\+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$
```

even that prob does not cover all valid email addresses though...

Comment: Thanks... and yes you are right... it'll not cover all the valid email addresses... i can continue playing with it.. :)