# Email Check for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i'm working on my site, but i have a problem with the email checker, i dont get why it wont work (I HAVE NEVER USED JS BEFORE)
so i did like that:

```
var flag=true;

    var st = Form1["email"].value.indexOf("@");

    if (st == -1)

    {

        alert("You must insert @ in email address.");

        flag=false;

    }
```

Can some one help me?
thanks for the help

Comment: Check this thread,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940577/javascript-regular-expression-email-validation

Solved using regular expressions.

Comment: You need to learn Javascript.

Comment: @zenith how do you learn without trying things and encountering stuff that you don't understand?  Books and articles only go so far.  (Now why do they ask write my code questions...)

Comment: @ben336 "Books and articles only go so far" - I wouldn't say that, good books have endless possibilities. I'd rather spend a few hours reading beforehand and save myself time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are your friend, try this:

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]  {1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Comment: Great, now I have 2 problems ;)

Comment: Why are you allowing spaces in the host part?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var regex = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+([0-9a-zA-Z]*[-._+])*[0-9a-zA-Z]+@[0-9a-zA-Z]+([-.][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*([0-9a-zA-Z]*[.])[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;

   if (regex.test(Form1["email"].value) == false) 
   {
   alert("Invalid E-mail address!");
   }
```