# Check if Input Value is an email Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that check if an email exists, It works right, but I have a dude, How can I check if the var is an email?

here's my code:

```
$('#email').change(function email_check(){  
var email = $('#email').val();
if(email == "" || email.length < 4){
$('#email').css('border', '3px #CCC solid');
$('#tic').hide();
}else{

jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "c.php",
   data: 'email='+ email,
   cache: false,
   success: function(response){
if(response == 1){
    $('#email').css('border', '3px #C33 solid');    
    $('#tic').hide();
    $('#cros').fadeIn();
    noemail = 1;
    }else{
    $('#email').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
    $('#cros').hide();
    $('#tic').fadeIn();
    noemail = 0;
         }
}
});
}
});
```

Comment: Just check if it contains an @ with something in the front and back.

Comment: well, @Jack finally i made it how you said me, but different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

technically, JavaScript can only check if the text entered matches a particular criteria. Even server-side languages have trouble determining if the email address entered is valid as you actually need to send an email to the address and wait for a response from the mail server. This response can be not helpful as there are several conditions where the mail server will not return a response.

Check out some responses to this same question: [JavaScript Regular Expression Email Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940577/javascript-regular-expression-email-validation)

Comment: Well, I checked the responses and it helped me, thanks a lot.