# Validating email in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var emailRegex =/^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)
(?<=[0-9a-z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,24}))$/
```

**above pattern for email validations giving Error:**

```
")" is not valid at the start of a code block. 
 Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ozeyag/19/edit from link by user2064000

Comment: @Degnome it's working fine in jsbin but in Visual Studio it is giving error Error: Unexpected character '\'

Comment: You have an unescaped `/` in the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is probably the best way.

```
function validate(email) { 
var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;  
if (emailPattern.test(email.value) == false) 
    {
        alert('Invalid Email Address');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This should be validated on the server side as well.

Comment: Error: Unexpected character '\' and also showing red line after 3rd '@'

Comment: same error as explained in question

Comment: `abc@com` is a valid address, `abc@xxx.museum` also.

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern

```
 var pattern = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
```

also check this

[JavaScript Regular Expression Email Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940577/javascript-regular-expression-email-validation)

Comment: `abc@com` is a valid address, `abc@xxx.museum` also.