# JavaScript Regex E-Mail Validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm really new to regex in general. All I need is it to check and make sure (Something@something.something) works. I've tried this.

```
var checkEmail = /^\w+@\w+.[a-zA-Z]/;
```

Is something like this correct for what I'm looking for?

Comment: Couldn't you test this yourself? Like at http://regexpal.com/

Comment: This may be a good start -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940577/javascript-regular-expression-email-validation

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery regex validation of e-mail address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855865/jquery-regex-validation-of-e-mail-address)

Comment: @j08691 I would have if I knew this website existed. Thanks for showing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refine what you have:

```
var checkEmail = /^\w+@\w+\.[a-zA-Z]+/;
```

What you posted it close (you should escape the `.` so it doesn't match any character and add a `+` after the `[a-zA-Z]` because top-level domains are at least 2 character I think), but for something like an email address that actually has a long and little known spec, I would just use someone else's regex.

Here's a site with more info:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Yeah, I've seen some very specific realistic regex for E-Mails, but this is just for a class assignment that doesn't need all the specifics. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the dot, otherwise it is a meta character that matches anything.   Try:

`/^\w+@\w+.[a-zA-Z]/`