# email validation pattern is not working for some testing patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am validating the email by adding the user and email to the list, the pattern that I provided is not working for some patterns like xyz.xyz kkk.kk and my message is not displaying when it is validating Here is my code..

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
    <h2>Add a User:</h2>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="name">
    <input id="email" type="text"  name="email" placeholder="email">
    <button onclick='return addUser();' type="submit">add user</button>
</form>

<h2>UsersList:</h2>
<ul id="users"></ul>
```

**JS**

```
function addUser(){
    var list = document.getElementById('users');
    var username =document.getElementById('username').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    if (email.value != '') 
    {
        reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
        if (reg.test(email.value) == true) {
            entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(username + ' ' + email.value));
            list.appendChild(entry);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            email.className += 'errorclass';
            email.innerHtml = "Please enter valid emailid";
            return false;                             

        }
```

**CSS**

```
.errorclass{
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

Comment: Relevant .. [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Here's the official regex for email addresses:
http://ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: Hi, try to be more precise when asking regex questions. What do you mean, 'not working'? It's matching where it shouldn't? The contrary? Does your message sometimes show up? Never? What do you want to validate (as in, give input and expected output)? And please do not to dump all your code in a block, keep only the relevant part.

Comment: when the page load my validation works and I tried again the validation is not working at all i think it is not regex pattern problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
```

with

```
 reg = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
```

Refer [JavaScript Regular Expression Email Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940577/javascript-regular-expression-email-validation)

Comment: validation is working on the page load.. it is not working when I tried enter the wrong email id