# Email validation is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

My email validation is not checking condition properly when i give without name only domain name in text box example `@gmail.com` it shows valid like valid email i need to raise alert this situation. but it works at checks domain name it works fine.

My code:

```
if(!(email.endsWith("@yahoo.com")  || email.endsWith("@gmail.com"))){
          alert("Email Should be in @yahoo.com or @gmail.com");
           $("#txtEmail").val('');
           document.getElementById("txtEmail").focus();
             return false; 
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: you can always add another check of `startsWith` if you are not thinking of `regex` which is pretty good  solution

Comment: Use regex to validate email

Comment: From what you posted the JS is doing what it's supposed to. I'd suggest using a regex to check the if the entered values are valid mail addresses and when that's the case you could check for yahoo/gmail.
 (btw: don't even try to write an email-regex, save yourself the trouble and google for a good one )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think regex is not a good solution, because he want to check if the email is from yahoo.com or gmail.com.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940577/javascript-regular-expression-email-validation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `email.lastIndexOf("@") === 0` to your condition, like this:

```
if(email.lastIndexOf("@") === 0 || !(email.endsWith("@yahoo.com") || email.endsWith("@gmail.com"))){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this kind of regexp

```
if (email.match(/^\S+@(yahoo|gmail)+\.com$/g))
```

This will check that you have content before the @ and validate that is it yahoo or gmail.