# Custom - Javascript regular expression to validate custom email addresses

Tags: javascript, angular6

I want it to be correct my JavaScript regex pattern to validate below email address scenarios

1. msekhar@yahoo.com
2. msekhar@cs.aau.edu
3. ms.sekhar@yahoo.com
4. ms_sekhar@yahoo.com
5. msekhar@cs2.aau.edu
6. msekhar@autobots.ai
7. msekhar@interior.homeland1.myanmar.mm
8. msekhar1922@yahoo.com
9. msekhar#21@autobots.com
10. \u001\u002@autobots.com

I have tried the following regex pattern but it's not validating all the above scenarios

```
/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/
```

Could any one please help me with this where am doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate question! Did you check the following?- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Regular Expression Email Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940577/javascript-regular-expression-email-validation)

Comment: Note, the the aforementioned referenced topics do not take into account unicode characters in the local part. See also SMTPUTF8 in [RFC6531](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6531)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex should do:

```
^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$
```

Test it: https://regex101.com/r/7gH0BR/2

EDIT: I have added all your test cases

Answer (score 0):

I have always used this one but note it doesn't trigger on escaped unicode:

```
^([\w\d._\-#])+@([\w\d._\-#]+[.][\w\d._\-#]+)+$
```

You can see how it works here: https://regex101.com/r/caa7b2/4

Comment: The use of international characters in the local-part have been introduced in 2012 as part of [RFC6531](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6531)

Answer (score 0):

First off `[_a-z0-9]+` is going to match the username fields for the majority of those testcases. Anything further testing of username field content will result in a mismatch. If you write a pattern that expects two `.`-delimitered fields, it'll match when you provide two `.`-delimitered fields and *only* then, not anything else. Make a mental note of that. I think you probably meant to put the `.` in the first character set, and omit this part here: `(.[_a-z0-9]+)`...

As for the domain part of the email address, similar story there... if you're trying to match domains containing two labels (`yahoo` and `com`) against a pattern that expects *three*... it's going to fail because there's one less label, right? There are domain names that only contain *one* label which you might want to recognise as email addresses, too, like `localhost`...

You know, there is a point to where you can dig yourself down a very deep rabbit hole trying to parse email addresses, much to the effect of [this question and answer sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). If you're making this complex using regular expressions... I think maybe a better tool is a proper parser generator... otherwise, write the following[image]:

1. A pattern that matches anything up until an `@` character
2. A pattern that matches the `@` character (this will help you learn how to avoid your `.`-related error)
3. A pattern that matches everything (this will help you understand your `.`-related error)
4. Combine the three above in the order presented.