# mysql php check form for empty input fields

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(empty($_POST['inputEmail'])) {       

    function valid_mail($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? $str : false;
}

echo 'Please enter a valid email address' . "<br />";

    }
```

Comment: can you post the rest of your code please.

Comment: consider to make javascript/client validations

Comment: @Haim Evgi - just as an addition, not standalone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || false === filter_var($_POST['inputEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo 'Please enter an email address' . "<br />";
    }
    elseif(empty($_POST['inputPostcode'])) {
        echo 'Please enter postcode' . "<br />";
    }
    else {
        // save to db here (no errors occured)
        // return; (or redirect, or whatever)
    }
}

// display form here
```

You may also use the `required`-attribute on required form-fields. You can also use [HTML5-input-types](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-email), like `<input type="mail" />` for client-side checks. Both methods which can be "hacked", but prevents "normal" user to send a not-correctly-filled form. Use PHP's [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)-function, to validate the mail-address on the server.

Answer (score 1):

use a temporary variable:

$validation_error = false;

```
if($_POST['inputEmail'] == ''){
    echo 'Please enter an email address' . "<br />";
    $validation_error = true;
}

if($_POST['inputPostcode'] == '')
    echo 'Please enter postcode' . "<br />";
    $validation_error = true;
}

// no error occured
if(!validation_error){
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better mail validation function could be:

```
/**
 * Return the mail address if it's valid or false otherwise
 */
function valid_mail($str) {
    $mail_regexp = '/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/';
    preg_match($mail_regexp, $str, $matches);
return strcmp($str, $matches[0]) ? false : $str;
}
```

or using PHP [filter_var](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) (thanks @feela)

```
function valid_mail($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? $str : false;
}
```

Comment: That regex would only match email-addresses in ASCII, what about IDN's? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613589/php-email-validation

Comment: jbrond thanks for your help so far. I am not sure where to include the email validation function. Where do I include it?? I have update code above.

Comment: @user921334 I've updated my answer, to include the validity check. Please revert your question-edit, as your question is no longer available. That is quite confusing, as the answers don't really match the new question. Just append your updated code, instead of replacing it…