# preg_match email validation. (Adding hyphen to domain spot)

Tags: php, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613589/php-email-validation)

I'm working on this website, where I have to make a register form. I made it work, but then my friend told me, that some email domain names does have hyphens in them, like;

test@test-tester.com

Right now my code look like this:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9._\-]\w+(\.\w+)*\@\w+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,6}$/", $_POST["email"]
```

What I can see, this should work, but it still does not allow the hyphen.
Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Regex is always useful, but I prefer to use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to validate emails

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    print('valid Email!');
}
else
{
    print('invalid-email =(');
}
```