# Escaping dangerous characters in emails in PHP

Tags: php, email, escaping

Is there a way to escape dangerous characters that can be exploited to malform emails sent through web forms? I am making a system with a signup script and want to protect the email field from being injected with a huge mailing list.

Comment: I think you're looking for an email Regex. It will make sure emails are 'something@somethineselse.com/net/org/etc.' and won't allow for mailing lists. http://komunitasweb.com/2009/03/10-practical-php-regular-expression-recipes/

Comment: Use an email sending library, it will take care of this sort of things for you

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS What exactly is your question? Bad emails or bad characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP email validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613589/php-email-validation)

Comment: Bad characters. It's a duplicate. Asking for close.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS use `addslashes()` or `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a php library for email address validation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161342/is-there-a-php-library-for-email-address-validation)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disregard my other answer.  I read your question wrong.

Here's a function I've been using to verify an email conforms to RFC standards:

```
preg_match("/^([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*)@((?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]))?$/i",$email)
```

Comment: Like most other email validation regexes, it allows invalid email addresses, and permits invalid ones.

Answer (score -1):

I believe `htmlspecialchars()` should do the trick.

Comment: Does it catch commas? Or other weird things that can be exploited?

Comment: You'll also want to consider combining that with `strip_tags` and `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: I suppose I don't know enough about email formatting to understand why commas would be dangerous, but if you want a more catch-all function `htmlentities` will convert *all* characters, not just the usual suspects.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars

Comment: Disregard my answer...  I read your question as relating to sending emails, not verifying email handles...

Comment: No this will produce semicolons, like in "&amp;", which will prevent the email from sending properly.