# What regexp does PHP filter_var use internally for FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL?

Tags: php, regex

Just out of curiosity, does anyone know how the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` flag works in `filter_var`? I assume it uses a regexp but mankind has long sought a perfect regexp for this task, I'd like to know what PHP is using.

Comment: See https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L499

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3613613/3574819