# BASH if comparison to force a valid e-mail address format is entered

Tags: bash

I have a useradd bash script which requests the user enter an e-mail address for the user being created. This is so the user receives his username/password in an e-mail when his/her account is created.

Currently this part of the code is very simple:

```
echo Enter the users e-mail address
read ADDRESS
```

What i'm finding is that sometimes when the operators run the script they are entereing blank information. How can I put a if statement in place that enforces they enter an e-mail address format.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work. The idea was to at least verify they are using the @ symbol.

```
if [[ $string != "@" ]] ; then
    echo You have entered an invalid e-mail address!
    exit 1
else
    # do something
fi
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138701/email-check-regular-expression-with-bash-script

Answer (score 4):

If you're just looking for something quick and dirty, this bash conditional expression will match something that has at least one char, an '@', at least one char, a dot, and at least one char.

```
[[ "$email" == ?*@?*.?* ]]
```

Examples

```
$ [[ "a@b.c" == ?*@?*.?* ]] && echo Y || echo n
Y
$ [[ "foo@bar" == ?*@?*.?* ]] && echo Y || echo n
n
```

Actual email validation is gnarly (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953197/rfc822-email-address-validation-with-regular-expressions/2953742#2953742))

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I actually have what I need with this regex: if [[ "$ADDRESS" =~ "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$" ]]

Answer (score 2):

`!=` tests for exact inequality:  the string would have to be exactly `@` with nothing else.  Two ways to do the test you want are

```
case "$string" in
*@*)
    ;;
*)
    echo You have entered an invalid email address! >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

or

```
if ! expr "$string" : '.*@' >/dev/null; then
    echo You have entered an invalid email address! >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

You need to redirect the result from `expr` because it will print the matched length.  Note also that `case` uses shell globs, whereas `expr` uses POSIX basic regular expressions (so you can't use `+`, `?`, etc.); and you need to quote the regex passed to `expr` so the shell doesn't expand it, but for `case` the whole point is to have the shell expand it.

I generally prefer the `case` one unless I actually need a regex.

Comment: Actuall, my bash manual says `==` and `!=` within `[[ ]]` are pattern matching operators.

Comment: @glenn: Are you sure?  That would break compatibility with POSIX pretty badly, and `bash` is supposed to be POSIX compatible. `=~` and `!~` are the pattern matching operators (and relatively new).

Comment: The way I read the man page, `=~` and `!~` are *regular expression* matching operators, and `==` and `!=` are *glob* (and extglob) matching operators. See the discussion of `[[...]]` in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)

Comment: Also, note the difference between `[[ "hello" == "hell?" ]]` and `[[ "hello" == hell? ]]`

Comment: @glenn: So the `bash` maintainers finally jettisoned any pretense of [POSIX compatibility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html)? Lovely. (One could quibble about `=` vs. `==`, but `!=` tests for identical strings.)

Answer (score 0):

You could e.g. use `bash`'s `=~` operator, e.g.:

```
if [[ $string =~ "@" ]] ; then
    # do something
else
    echo You have entered an invalid e-mail address!
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob-style patterns in `if` conditionals in bash:

```
if [[ $string != *"@"* ]] ; then
    echo You have entered an invalid e-mail address!
    exit 1
else
    # do something
fi
```

I'd go a step further and require at least one character at either side of the `@`:

```
if [[ $string != *?"@"?* ]] ; then
    echo You have entered an invalid e-mail address!
    exit 1
else
    : # do something
fi
```