# Validating multiple email addresses in a mailto: link

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex pattern to allow a mailto: link to have multiple email address

I tried below pattern:

```
 "((href|src)(\\S)*?=(\\S)*?)?(\"|'|)(((mailto:)?(?:[A-Z0-9._-])@(?:[A-Z0-9.-])\\.[A-Z]([,;]\\s*(?:[A-Z0-9._-])@(?:[A-Z0-9.-])\\.[A-Z])*(</a>)?))"
```

example:

```
<a href = mailto:abc@abc.com,sdf@abc.com>mail me</a>;
```

Is this regex pattern correct?

Comment: Please put 4 spaces before code so that it will be properly escaped and monotyped.  That will make it easier for people to read.

Comment: Your example is missing an end-quote. Is this intentional?

Comment: Very similar to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses

Comment: Check out a previous post on tools for validating RegEx... they are EXTREMELY useful! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965037/any-tools-for-creating-not-just-checking-regex

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard for some example regexps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - no.  There are valid email addresses that it will filter out.  For just a single example, `+` is a completely valid character in the local part of an email address (and an important one for many people) which you're going to reject.

Longer answer - no, and you're not going to write a regex that is "correct" in the technical sense (of conforming to [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1)).  Local parts can have almost any characters in them as they're interpreted by the target mailserver; they can also be enclosed in quotes.  The best approach is not to use regex for this at all but use a decent third-party validator.

Answer (score 0):

Validating multiple emails this way could be a overkill. Check this http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5427060&tstart=45 In case the emails are going to be from the same domain it can be simplified further.