# Regular expression which matches a pattern, or is an empty string

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation, string

I have the following Regular Expression which matches an email address format:

```
^[\w\.\-]+@([\w\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+$
```

This is used for validation with a form using JavaScript. However, this is an optional field. Therefore how can I change this regex to match an email address format, or an empty string?

From my limited regex knowledge, I think `\b` matches an empty string, and `|` means "Or", so I tried to do the following, but it didn't work:

```
^[\w\.\-]+@([\w\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+$|\b
```

Comment: If you *must* validate an email, be as permissive as possible. You'd be surprised how easy it is to miss real, valid and functional email addresses with home-baked regexes. Your regex, for instance,  will fail on these valid addresses: joe_blow@foo.com, micro$oft@apple.com, root@localhost, siegfried+roy@lasvegas.com.

Comment: Agreeing with Zano, just take a look at this regex http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: @Anders wow, thats a very complex regex! I think I've misunderestimated the complexity of regex

Comment: No, I think you've misunderestimated the complexity of email validation :-)

Answer (score 284, accepted):

To match `pattern` or an empty string, use

```
^$|pattern
```

#### Explanation

- `^` and `$` are the beginning and end of the string anchors respectively.
- `|` is used to denote alternates, e.g. `this|that`.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and [Alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

---

#### On `\b`

`\b` in most flavor is a "word boundary" anchor. It is a zero-width match, i.e. an empty string, but it only matches those strings at *very specific places*, namely at the boundaries of a word.

That is, `\b` is located:

- Between consecutive `\w` and `\W` (either order):

  - i.e. between a word character and a non-word character
- Between `^` and `\w`

  - i.e. at the beginning of the string if it starts with `\w`
- Between `\w` and `$`

  - i.e. at the end of the string if it ends with `\w`

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

---

#### On using regex to match e-mail addresses

This is not trivial depending on specification.

#### Related questions

- [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)
- [Regexp recognition of email address hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard)
- [How far should one take e-mail address validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation)

Answer (score 15):

An alternative would be to place your regexp in non-capturing parentheses. Then make that expression optional using the `?` qualifier, which will look for 0 (i.e. empty string) or 1 instances of the non-captured group.

For example:

```
/(?: some regexp )?/
```

In your case the regular expression would look something like this:

```
/^(?:[\w\.\-]+@([\w\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+)?$/
```

No `|` "or" operator necessary!

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is the Mozilla documentation for JavaScript Regular Expression syntax.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure why you'd want to validate an optional email address, but I'd suggest you use

```
^$|^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+$
```

meaning

```
^$        empty string
|         or
^         beginning of string
[^@\s]+   any character but @ or whitespace
@         
[^@\s]+
$         end of string
```

You won't stop fake emails anyway, and this way you won't stop valid addresses.

Comment: If an address isn't entered into the field, a NULL value is entered into the database, therefore this can be dealt with when it comes to sending out newsletters etc. I appreciate this won't stop fake addresses, and I don't think thats possible at all with Regex, but it'll at least minimise human-error

Comment: I also have customers request this frequently as well. It is really just to keep customers from doing something stupid like entering their phone number in the email field.

Comment: Just wanted to check for an empty String. ^$ worked

Answer (score 1):

\b matches a word boundary. I think you can use ^$ for empty string.

Answer (score 0):

**^$** did not work for me if there were multiple patterns in regex.

Another solution:

```
/(pattern1)(pattern2)?/g
```

"pattern2" is optional. If empty, not matched.

**?** matches (pattern2) between zero and one times.

Tested here ("m" is there for multi-line example purposes): https://regex101.com/r/mezfvx/1