# Regex doesn't work in String.matches()

Tags: java, regex

I have this small piece of code

```
String[] words = {"{apf","hum_","dkoe","12f"};
for(String s:words)
{
    if(s.matches("[a-z]"))
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Supposed to print

```
dkoe
```

but it prints nothing!!

Comment: Java's `matches` puts a ^ at the start and a $ at the end of regexes for you. So `matches("[a-z]")` will actually look for /^[a-z]$/ instead.

Comment: Yes @Robino you are absolutely right.

Comment: Surely, if you expect `matches` to look for any occurrence of `[a-z]`, then it should match them all? I would not expect `matches` to check each and every character individually against  the regex.

Comment: @Robino: Where is that functionality described/documented?

Comment: @Toru  On the java docs page for String.Matches - where else? A casual Google of "java string matches documentation" reveals, in the top result, the phrase "str.matches(regex) yields exactly the same result as the expression". The important word is "exactly".

Comment: @PhilHibbs Yes, that was my expectation also!

Answer (score 410, accepted):

Welcome to Java's misnamed [`.matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) method... It tries and matches ALL the input. Unfortunately, other languages have followed suit :(

If you want to see if the regex matches an input text, use a `Pattern`, a `Matcher` and the `.find()` method of the matcher:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputstring);
if (m.find())
    // match
```

If what you want is indeed to see if an input only has lowercase letters, you can use `.matches()`, but you need to match one or more characters: append a `+` to your character class, as in `[a-z]+`. Or use `^[a-z]+$` and `.find()`.

Comment: i find 100s of incomplete tutorials online. Couldn't find a good one. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Thanx @fge for explain `.matches()`. May be you know why `.find()` works so slow in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603729/matcher-dont-find-on-2nd-step)?

Comment: What do you mean by *other languages followed suit*? From what I know, only C++ has an equivalent set of methods - `regex_search` and `regex_match`. In Python, `re.match` only anchors the match at the start of the string (as if it were `\Apattern`) and Python 3.x has got a nice `.fullmatch()` method. In JS, Go, PHP and .NET, the there are no regex methods that anchor the match implicitly. ElasticSearch, XML Schema and HTML5/Validators Angluar patterns  are always anchored by default. In Swift/Objective C, there is a way to anchor the pattern at the start with an option.

Comment: Is there a oneliner way to do this?

Comment: That feeling when you waste hours wondering what's wrong with your regex and end up on this SO answer realising that you've already upvoted it long time ago...

Comment: It is true String#matches() matches the entire string by default but `"123abc".matches("^[0-9]+.*$")` or `"123abc".matches("[0-9]+.*")`  works too

Answer (score 51):

`[a-z]` matches a **single** char between a and z. So, if your string was just `"d"`, for example, then it would have matched and been printed out.

You need to change your regex to `[a-z]+` to match one or more chars.

Comment: Of course it matches a single char, that's what that regexp does! What isn't clear however (and should not be the case either!) is that java puts the prefix `^` and suffix `$` around the provided regexp, altering it unwantedly and creating weird bugs. They should not do that, because that's not how the initial regexp was meant.

Answer (score 33):

`String.matches` returns whether the *whole* string matches the regex, not just any substring.

Comment: Something that is really a sad reality is that you are right. I really don't know why they did it this way.

Answer (score 17):

java's implementation of regexes try to match the whole string

that's different from perl regexes, which try to find a matching part

if you want to find a string with nothing but lower case characters, use the pattern `[a-z]+`

if you want to find a string containing at least one lower case character, use the pattern `.*[a-z].*`

Comment: more info [here](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-pattern-matching-matches-method-not-working)

Comment: Why is this [not documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))?!

Answer (score 13):

Used

```
String[] words = {"{apf","hum_","dkoe","12f"};
    for(String s:words)
    {
        if(s.matches("[a-z]+"))
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem once:

```
Pattern ptr = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z][\\']?[a-zA-Z\\s]+$");
```

The above failed!

```
Pattern ptr = Pattern.compile("(^[a-zA-Z][\\']?[a-zA-Z\\s]+$)");
```

The above worked with pattern within `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression `[a-z]` doesn't match `dkoe` since it only matches Strings of lenght 1. Use something like `[a-z]+`.

Answer (score -2):

you must put at least a capture `()` in the pattern to match, and correct pattern like this:

```
String[] words = {"{apf","hum_","dkoe","12f"};
for(String s:words)
{
    if(s.matches("(^[a-z]+$)"))
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brackets didn't change anything.

Comment: @Touniouk without brackets `matches` not have any output.

Answer (score -3):

You can make your pattern case insensitive by doing:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```