# A cleaner if statement with multiple comparisons

Tags: java, if-statement

The following statement just looks very messy when you have a lot of terms:

```
if(a.equals("x") || a.equals("y") || a.equals("z") || Any number of terms...... )
    //Do something
```

Is there a cleaner way of performing the same action, I would like my code to be as readable as possible.

NOTE: x, y and z are just placeholders for any string of any length.  There could be 20 string terms here of variable length in if condition each being OR'd together

Comment: It really depends upon the context. There are so many options here depending upon the purpose of the condition, and the items being compared.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this was just a general example and not really the problem you were facing, right?

Comment: Why not try with RegEx. if(a.matches("[xyz]"))...

Comment: Yeah this is a general question

Comment: @AllanMacmillan haha, now you have a lot of upvoted answers here, which do not answer your question at all :D

Comment: @noone: I concur. Although I like to think my answer is the best one, by far the best thing to do is to leave the code as it is and get used to those long `if` statements.

Comment: How many terms count as "a lot"?

Comment: @AllanMacmillan I think "It depends" is an appropriate answer here.  If you are looking for a quick fix, there are already a myriad of different ways offered here.  However, if this problem is talked about in a more general sense, I would suggest you to look into design patterns (as many others have alluded to in their answers) for a deeper solution.  It *really* depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: The answer to this question will depend strongly on your particular situation.  You haven't provided enough context for anyone to really give a good answer.  This question will generate a lot of answers and most of them won't be applicable to your specific case.

Comment: @Leo's would be best if it was standard... if (a.equalsAny("x", "y", "z")). Generally though it will be better to just keep it what everyone knows and format it nicely.

Comment: What Susai says. Why not use a regular expression? Clean and simple.

Comment: Always keep in mind that extracting (complicated) logical expressions into boolean returning functions/methods is a clean way to reduce code complexity. A method call with a proper name is much readable and cleaner than complex logical stuff - and you can also write separate unit tests for the function containing the logic.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
Set<String> stuff = new HashSet<String>();
stuff.add("x");
stuff.add("y");
stuff.add("z");
if(stuff.contains(a)) {
    //stuff
}
```

If this is a tight loop you can use a static Set.

```
static Set<String> stuff;
static {
    stuff = new HashSet<String>();
    stuff.add("x");
    stuff.add("y");
    stuff.add("z");
}

//Somewhere else in the cosmos

if(stuff.contains(a)) {
    //stuff
}
```

And if you want to be extra sure nothing is getting modified while you're not looking.

```
Set<String> test = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>() {
        {
            add("x");
            add("y");
            add("z");
        }
    });
```

If you just want to get some logic in there for a handful of hard coded conditions then one of the switch or if statement with newlines solutions might be better.  But if you have a lot of conditions then it might be good to separate your configuration from logic.

Comment: Shorter version: `Collections.addAll(stuff, "x", "y", "z");`

Comment: This still has poor readability in the sense that it uses up many lines if you have a lot of Strings

Comment: @AllanMacmillan It has much less line noise though, and you end up doing a single comparison in the end. This is the commonly accepted pattern to the general question you asked.

Comment: Yes, if it's `static` data, it definitely should be declared `static`.

Comment: +1 for "Somewhere else in the cosmos"

Comment: @AllanMacmillan this has much greater readability because you are able to give `stuff` a name with meaning.

Comment: Am I the only user on SO who thinks this answer is terrible? So much overhead. And `stuff` is detached from the logic of the `if` statement so becomes hard to read.

Comment: Haha, if the asker really wants to just get the logic in there then a switch or if statement with newlines between conditions probably is the better route.  Now I suspect that might be what was wanted and I got carried away with the, "I KNOW THIS ANSWER!" high.  Though, if there are a lot, A LOT, of conditions then it might actually be best to separate the configuration from the logic.

Comment: If you can't beat 'em, join 'em. Have an upvote ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba Almost invariably massive blocks of code inside an `if` condition are not the optimum vz. readability. This is especially so due to the large number of *degrees of freedom* in a general Boolean expression: to be sure the whole thing amounts to just checking set membership, you must carefully inspect each clause, minding any parentheses, misspellings of the repeated variable name, and more.  That is where the true advantage of the set approach comes in: the strong constraint on those degrees of freedom.

Comment: You should just be glad I didn't post the Spring solution using an XML configuration of the set.

Comment: @HahaHortness That would be why people say "Java is slow".  Maybe it's because Java makes it easy for you guys to do things like that.  But you need to stop.  Put the XML down.

Comment: Sir, you can insult my family, my body, my race, my religion, my politics, but I will not let you insult XML.

Comment: Clever, but ultimately less readable IMO. It makes the `if` condition look cleaner but then you're left looking around for anything that has mutated `stuff`. I could probably be convinced otherwise though.

Comment: @Bathsheba: That’s the fault of Java, not the fault of the solution. *The* way to factor out `a ==` from `a == 'x' || a == 'y'` is `['x', 'y'].contains(a)`, by the definition of `contains`.

Answer (score 46):

What do you think looks "unclean" about it?

If you have a bunch of complicated boolean logic, you might separate the different parts of it into individual boolean variables and refer to them in the if statement.

Or you could create a function that takes your 'a' variable and returns a boolean. You'd just be hiding your logic in the method, but it would clean up your if statement.

Comment: I think this is the only valid answer here. All others just solve an example problem and do not help anyhow in general.

Comment: I concur with @noone. The question is too vague to be answered well.

Comment: Not that OP was concerned with it, but breaking it out to another function will help with unit testing as well.

Comment: @crush I smiled reading this. There is noone that you concur with.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung Sure, but when you read it, all you hear in your head is "no one".

Comment: Moving the logic into method with a descriptive name - such as `isValidFooChar` in this case - would improve code readability in many cases.

Answer (score 27):

Alternatively, if you are using Java 7+ you can use strings in switch/case. For example (I extracted this from an Oracle doc and modified)

```
         switch (str) {

             case "x":
             case "y":
             case "z":
                 //do action
                 break;
             default:
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument not matched "+str);

    }
```

Here is the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)

Comment: @keshlam - you missed the OP's note "x, y and z are just placeholders for any string of any length."

Comment: And this only works with strings.. and you have to know the cases, it's not a good solution for big possibilities.

Answer (score 24):

Use a *regular expression*

```
If (a.matches("[xyz]")){
    // matches either "x", "y", or "z"
```

or, for longer strings,

```
If (a.matches("one|two|three")){
    // matches either "one", "two" or "three"
```

But this is computationally expensive, but probably not much worse than instantiating a `set` etc. But it's the clearest way I can think of.

*But* in the end, the nicest way is probably to leave things as they are, with an adjustment to the formatting:

```
if (a.equals("x") || 
    a.equals("y") || 
    a.equals("z")
    ){
```

There is then absolutely no ambiguity in what the code is doing and so your code will be easier to maintain. If performance matters, you can even put the most likely occurrences towards the top of the list.

Comment: Probably required, yes!

Comment: Wouldn't this match `'asfsbxaskdfk'`? seems it should be `^[xyz]$`

Comment: @crush No, `matches` requires a match against the complete input sequence.

Comment: I don’t think, it’s “computationally expensive”. Depending on the actual strings it can be even faster than all other approaches (multiple `equals` or using `Set`s). A `HashSet` uses an expensive hashing operation which pays off for a large number of `String`s only. On the other hand, the regular expression implementation can be more efficient than `equals` for large `String`s due to its internal optimizations.

Comment: You should've started your answer with ["Everybody stand back!"](http://xkcd.com/208/).

Comment: Yep thats the way to go. Regexp clean and simple ...

Comment: In your final code block, move the `||` fr each line to the next line. You can now remove any line without a dangling or to tidy up.

Answer (score 22):

### Reaching for semantics

On a semantic level, what you are checking for is *set membership*. However, you implement it on a very low level, basically *inlining* all the code needed to achieve the check. Apart from forcing the reader to infer the intent behind that massive condition, a prominent issue with such an approach is the large number of *degrees of freedom* in a general Boolean expression: to be sure the whole thing amounts to just checking set membership, one must carefully inspect each clause, minding any parentheses, misspellings of the repeated variable name, and more.

Each loose degree of freedom means exposure to not just one more bug, but to one more *class* of bugs.

An approach which uses an explicit set would have these advantages:

- clear and explicit semantics;
- tight constraint on the degrees of freedom to look after;
- O(1) time complexity vs. O(n) complexity of your code.

This is the code needed to implement a set-based idiom:

```
static final Set<String> matches = 
                            unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<>(asList("a","b","c")));
...

if (matches.contains(a)) // do something;
```

*<sub>I'm implying `import static java.util.Arrays.asList` and  `import static java.util.Collections.unmodifiableSet`</sub>

Comment: Why `Set`? and not List?

Comment: @MariuszS See nachokk's comment :)

Comment: List searches linearly, no? At best, you'd do a binary search on a list. Hashset is O(1) because you have a hash code key.

Comment: Collections.addAll saves one list object creation (yes I know, makes no difference)

Comment: List is O(N) to check for membership, set is O(1). Much faster for larger collections.

Comment: @assylias The important difference (for me) is that `Collections.addAll` cannot be used in a single expression.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes I know you fight for line count!

Comment: Should be `Arrays.asList`

Comment: @nachokk not if you have an `import static java.util.Arrays.asList;`

Comment: In the event that you have 5+ elements in your list, or your elements are long words, it might be more readable to break each onto its own line.

Comment: @assylias it wasn't when i wrote my comment ;)

Comment: It seems this would have slightly greater overhead than calling `add()` for each element individually. `asList` creates an `ArrayList` which then Iterates over the `Collection` and calls `add()` on each element of the collection anyways. Of course, since this is a static set, the extra cost would only be at application start. For that reason, it might be so negligible that it's not worth considering.

Comment: @crush Yes, it's more than negligible: it's a single `String[]`, a tiny `List` wrapper instance around it, and then the iteration, which is again very much optimized in Java.

Comment: @TimB Not for a `TreeSet` (`O(log(n))`)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yeah, just remembered that Java Array doesn't inherit Collection. They inherit ICollection in C#. Dealing in multiple languages = brainf*ck. I swap between 6-7 languages every day :(

Comment: @ZouZou yes, but you would use a `HashSet` not a `TreeSet` for this...no need for ordering...

Comment: @TimB I just wanted to point out that it's not `O(1)` because of a set.

Comment: I like your update, i would +1 again but i can't . If he has to do search with 100 string or 1000 i don't think time complexity change a lot. it's still O(1) or im confused?

Comment: @nachokk If we use a HashSet, the complexity is O(1), which means it doesn't depend on the number of set elements. I'm not sure if that's what you are asking,  though.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i see, but perhaps object creation takes more time than  using a list if it were few elements

Comment: @nachokk Which object creation do you have in mind? There is none inside the if condition, whether a list or a set is used.

Comment: array + List + Set + unmodifiableSet

Comment: and i don't know why you got few upvotes , this is the best answer

Comment: @nachokk But that allocation happens only once, at class init time, and is really *very* lightweight: array is just 4 bytes per entry and isn't even retained; `unmodifiableSet` is a minimal (24 bytes or so, constant) wrapper around the main Set; same for the List (wraps the array), plus it also isn't retained; which leaves the `HashSet`, not so lightweight, but turns an O(n) operation into O(1), thus paying itself off. BTW thanks for the support :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Is the *degrees of freedom* a standard terminology or created by you?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Specifically how would you define *degrees of freedom* in  the context of programming?

Comment: @Geek It is in attempt to verbalize my intuition: each OR operand can be any boolean expression---that's one degree of freedom per operand. Opposed to that, each element of a `Set<String>` must be a String and the compiler will complain if it isn't---there are no degrees of freedom there.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik +1. I learnt a lot from your answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

### Readability Is Mostly Formatting

Not readable...

```
if(a.equals("x") || a.equals("y") || a.equals("z") || Any number of terms...... )
    //Do something
```

Now easy to real...

```
if(a.equals("x") || 
   a.equals("y") || 
   a.equals("z") ||
   Any number of terms...... )
    //Do something
```

Readability is very subjective to the person reading the source code.

If I came across code that implements collections, loops or one of the many other complicated answers here. I'd shake my head in disbelieve.

### Separate The Logic From The Problem

You are mixing two different things. There is the problem of making the business logic easy to read, and the problem of implementing the business logic.

```
 if(validState(a))
     // Do something
```

How you implement `validState` doesn't matter. What's important is that *code* with the if statement is readable as *business logic*. It should not be a long chain of Boolean operations that *hide* the intent of what is happening.

Here is an example of *readable business logic*.

```
if(!isCreditCard(a)) {
    return false;
}
if(isExpired(a)) {
    return false;
}
return paymentAuthorized(a);
```

At some level there has to be code that processes basic logic, strings, arrays, etc.. etc.. *but* it shouldn't be at this level.

If you find you often have to check if a string is equal to a bunch of other strings. Put that code into a string utility class. Separate it from your work and keep your code readable. By ensuring it shows what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).This is the simplest approach and less verbosity.

`Arrays.asList("x","y","z"...).contains(a)`

For performance reason if your collection is too big you could put data in a `HashSet` cause searching there is in constant time.

Example make your own util method

```
public final class Utils{

    private Utils(){}//don't let instantiate

    public static <T> boolean contains(T a,T ... x){
      return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(x)).contains(a);
    }
}
```

Then in your client code:

```
if(Utils.contains(a,"x","y","z","n")){
  //execute some code
}
```

Comment: This is a syntax error... it should be `Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a","b","c"...})`

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow more likely `Arrays.asList("a","b","c");`

Comment: @nachokk You should take your own advice to "read more on `Collections.addAll`" :) It's a `boolean` method. Also, by `#` you imply an instance method; you should use `.` both for `asList` and `addAll`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks i didn't know that `#` was for instance, and `.` to class level methods (static)

Comment: Well, it's a semi-convention, carried over from Ruby.

Answer (score 7):

With a little bit of help, you can get the syntactic sugar of a nicer if-statement with just a tiny bit of overhead. To elaborate on Tim's recommendation and Jesko's recommendation a tad further...

```
public abstract class Criteria {

  public boolean matchesAny( Object... objects ) {
    for( int i = 0, count = objects.length; i < count; i++ ) {
      Object object = objects[i];
      if( matches( object ) ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public boolean matchesAll( Object... objects ) {
    for( int i = 0, count = objects.length; i < count; i++ ) {
      Object object = objects[i];
      if( !matches( object ) ) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public abstract boolean matches( Object object );

}

public class Identity extends Criteria {

  public static Identity of( Object self ) {
    return new Identity( self );
  }

  private final Object self;

  public Identity( Object self ) {
    this.self = self;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean matches( Object object ) {
    return self != null ? self.equals( object ) : object == null;
  }

}
```

Your if-statement would then look like this:

```
if( Identity.of( a ).matchesAny( "x", "y", "z" ) ) {
  ...
}
```

This is sort of a middle ground between having a generic syntax for this sort of conditional matching and having the expression describe a specific intent. Following this pattern also lets you perform the same sort of matching using criteria other than equality, much like how `Comparator`s are designed.

Even with the improved syntax, this conditional expression is still just a little bit too complex. Further refactoring might lead to externalizing the terms `"x", "y", "z"` and moving the expression into a method whose name clearly defines its intent:

```
private static final String [] IMPORTANT_TERMS = {
  "x",
  "y",
  "z"
};

public boolean isImportant( String term ) {
  return Identity.of( term ).matchesAny( IMPORTANT_TERMS );
}
```

...and your original if-statement would finally be reduced to...

```
if( isImportant( a ) ) {
  ...
}
```

That's much better, and now the method containing your conditional expression can more readily focus on Doing One Thing.

Comment: Adding an extra layer of abstraction and giving it a concise name is a great way to improve readability. +1

Answer (score 6):

Independent of what you are trying to achieve, this

> ```
> if(a.equals("x") || a.equals("y") || a.equals("z") || Any number of terms...... )
>     //Do something
> ```

is *always messy and unclean.* In the first place it is just too long to make sense of it quickly.

The **simplest solution** for me would be to express your intend instead of being explicit.

Try to do this instead:

```
   public class SomeClass{
    public void SomeMethod(){
        if ( matchesSignificantChar(a) ){
          //doSomething
        }    
    }
    private bool matchesSignificantChar(String s){
        return (s.equals("x") || s.equals("y") || s.equals("z") || Any number of terms......    )
      }
   }
```

This **simplifies the scope** of your conditional statement and makes it easier to understand while moving the complexity to a much **smaller and named** scope, that is headed by your intend.

However, this is still not very extensible. If you try to make it cleaner, you can extract the boolean method into another class and pass it as a delegate to SomeClass'es Constructor or even to SomeMethod. Also you can look into the Strategy Pattern for even more exensiblity.

Keep in mind that as a programmer you will spend much more time reading code (not only yours) than writing it, so creating better understandable code will pay off in the long run.

Comment: I believe this doesn't address what the OP asked. The OP (probably) wanted an alternative to the expression `s.equals("x") || ...`, not getting rid of `if` simply putting the condition inside a method as a black box. Using a method for a complex condition is a good idea *but* you should also address how to write that condition in a readable way to completely answer the question.

Comment: @Bakuriu I appreciate your comment. I am offering another perspective  based on my interpretation of the question. My suggestion touches on the fact that putting this specific statement into a closed **named/titled** scope which will make the statement itself more understandable. So, there might not even be a reason to change it at all. However, if the OP thinks that the statement is still not understandable I suggested more possibilities. The OP will surely select the most appropriate answer himself and I am glad to provide more insight if required.

Answer (score 5):

I use following pattern

```
boolean cond = false; // Name this variable reasonably

cond = cond || a.equals("x");
cond = cond || a.equals("y");
cond = cond || a.equals("z");

// Any number of terms......

if (cond) {
    // ...
}
```

Note: no objects created on the heap. Also you can use any conditions, not only "equals".

In ruby you can use operator `||=` for this purpose like `cond ||= a.equals("x")`.

Comment: If `a` is the first thing checked then this will execute a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: This is not true. If `a` is `"x"`, then cond becomes `true` and no more `equals()` get called. The tiny overhead evaluating `cond == true` doesn't matter much.

Comment: Lazy eval makes this nice. I'd usually go for this unless this particular problem is _all over the place_. If it's not, this won't force me to eventually look into another layer of abstraction if I have to maintain the code. TL;DR +1

Answer (score 4):

The `Set` answer is good. When not comparing for membership of a collection you can also separate out some or all of the conditional statement into methods. For example

```
if (inBounds(x) && shouldProcess(x) ) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If a is guaranteed to be of length 1, you could do:

```
if ("xyz".indexOf(a) != -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One really nice way to do something like this is to use ASCII values, assuming your actual case here is where a is a char or a single character string. Convert a to its ASCII integer equivalent, then use something like this:

If you want to check that a is either "t", "u", "v", ... , "z", then do.....

If (val >= 116 && val <= 122) {//code here}

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use regexp like few [guys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20952439/2835239) wrote upper.
But also  you can use next code

```
private boolean isOneMoreEquals(Object arg, Object... conditions) {
    if (conditions == null || arg == null) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0, d = conditions.length; i < d; i++) {
        if (arg.equals(conditions[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

so your code will be next:

```
if (isOneMoreEquals(a, "x", "y", "z") {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `"x"`, `"y"`, and `"z"` can be of arbitrary length, you can use

```
if (0 <= java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(new String[] { "x", "y", "z" }, a)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Just make sure that you list your items in lexicographic order, as required by `binarySearch()`.  That should be compatible all the way back to Java 1.2, and it should be more efficient than the solutions that use Java Collections.

Of course, if your `"x"`, `"y"`, and `"z"` are all single characters, and `a` is also a character, you can use `if (0 <= "xyz".indexOf(a)) { ... }` or

```
switch (a) {
  case 'x': case 'y': case 'z':
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Why would this be more efficient than a hash set collection?  Binary search is O(log n) while Searching in a hash set is O(1).  (Of course in both cases creating the collection would be at least O(n))

Comment: @Taemyr For small inputs, Big-O analysis is misleading, as overhead costs dominate. The cost of creating a `HashSet<String>` may not be worthwhile.

Comment: Yes.  But is the init cost of the collection much worse than the set up for the Array?

Answer (score 0):

If x,y,z... is Consecutive， you can use if(a >= 'x' && a <= '...'), if not, you can use ArrayList or just Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think that cleanest and fastest way is to put values in array.

```
String[] values={"value1","value2","value3"};
for (string value : values) {
    if (a.equals(value){
        //Some code
    }
}
```