# java: most concise way to compare one variable against several others

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax

Often I find myself writing if statements like this...

```
if (name.equals("fred") || name.equals("bob") || name.equals("jack")){

}
```

or with primitives...

```
if (numb==4 || numb==45 || numb=91){

}
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?

edit: My question is indeed a duplicate. To anyone reading this, I recommmend having a look at the other threads too - they have some good stuff.

Comment: `switch`......? [The switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: what is gonna happen if you have && instead of ||?

Comment: @KickButtowski That doesn't make sense. A value cannot be equal to multiple primitives, right?

Comment: @k_g I did not talk about this specific situation, yet I asked in general?

Comment: Another duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952325/a-cleaner-if-statement/20952404#20952404

Comment: I don't think this should be a duplicate. yes, regarding strings, it is, but the original poster also asked for other objects and primitives. This isn't a String exclusive post.

Comment: If you have a moderately large number of strings, consider using a `Set`.  Besides efficiency (since it will look for a hash instead of comparing with every string), it makes it easier to encapsulate the place where your `Set` is created, and possibly put the set data in a place that's more logical in your program.  Also makes it easier to customize the data in the `Set` (e.g. if you're looking for a set of user commands, but then want to support users who speak a different language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `switch` and `case` statements:

for example instead of:

```
if (numb==4 || numb==45 || numb=91){
    //do stuff
}
```

you could do:

```
switch(numb){
    case 4:
    case 45:
    case 91:
        //do something regarding the numbers 4 45 and 91
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

If you are big on readability (since it is what this question is concerned about), you could also create line breaks between the boolean checks:

```
if(name.veryLongMethodHere("fred") ||
   name.veryLongMethodHere("bob") ||
   name.veryLongMethodHere("food")){
    //do more stuff   
}
```

this is a very good way to organize code if you have very long and complicated methods.

Even better yet, using regex for String objects:
    if(name.matches("bob|food|fred"){
        //do something
    }

Comment: Doesn't look more concise to me...

Comment: If you have 30 choices, it is, and more readable imo.

Comment: @August I find it a lot more readable and easy to format.

Comment: what is gonna happen if you have && instead of ||?

Comment: @KickButtowski What number is equal to 4, 45, and 91 all at once? That is a nonsensical situation.

Comment: @approachingDarknessFish +1 for amazing username XD :P and because it is helpful

Answer (score 2):

## You could...

Use a switch statement...

```
switch (name) {
    case "fred":
    case "bob":
    case "jack":
        break;
}
```

And

```
switch (numb) {
    case 4:
    case 45:
    case 91:
        break;
}
```

## You could...

Use a `Collection` of some type...

```
if (Arrays.asList("fred", "bob", "jack").contains("fred")) {
    // Have match
}
```

Which is useful if you have dynamic values...

You could also use something like...

```
if (Arrays.asList("fred", "bob", "jack").containsAll(Arrays.asList("fred", "bob", "jack"))) {
    // Have match
}
```

If you need to to use `&&` instead of `||`...

You could also substitute the long hand `String` list with a predefined array or `List`, which could allow you to write a single method...

```
public <T> boolean matchOR(List<T> want, T have) {

    return want.contains(have);

}

public <T> boolean matchAnd(List<T> want, List<T> have) {

    return want.containsAll(have);

}
```

Which would allow you to write something like...

```
if (matchOr(Arrays.asList("fred", "bob", "jack"), name)) {
    //...
}
```

As an idea...

At some point, context will need to be considered, for example, the above examples allow you to provide a flexible series of conditions, but you might not want to do this and will have to write your `if` statements as you have been

Comment: how about if you had && instead of ||?

Comment: Might be interesting to add to your answer that switching on a String is supported since Java 7.

Comment: @KickButtowski Then you can't do it, obviously, but that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: @KickButtowski Also, a value can't be `==2` and `==5` simultaneously. Just skip that block.

Comment: @k_g good point to address, but I asked that in general

Comment: @KickButtowski Use a separate case block

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you please be kind and address that inside your post so I can vote u up?

Comment: @KickButtowski Huh? In what case would you have multiple equalities containing the same variable? Can you give a situation?j

Comment: :D I dont ask about this specific condition. I am talking about other cases that you need to have multiple &&

Comment: The original poster is asking for a check with multiple possibilities, I don't see the third option as more efficient, because it doesn't shorten the `if` statement if you need to check for more than one thing.

EDIT: nevermind XD you edited it.

Comment: @KickButtowski Take a look at the last example

Comment: @KickButtowski Link me up

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is that you shouldn't always go for more "concise". Go for what's most readable, unless you're experiencing some kind of efficiency problem.

That being said, I'll throw in yet another way to do this:

```
    if(Arrays.asList("fred", "bob", "jack").contains(name)){

    }
```