# Check if a variable is equal to a list in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, variables

I want to check if the variable foo is equal to a list of values in *java*

```
if( foo == "Cheese" || foo == "a" || foo == "3" ) {
    // ...
}
```

I want to know how to do something like the following :

```
String[] values = {"Cheese", "a", "3"};
if( foo in values ) {
    // ...
}
```

Thank you for helping me !

Comment: `List.contains()`? Or maybe `List.equals()`, depending one what you actually mean by `foo==1` etc.

Comment: Do you mean like the SQL `IN` keyword? Like  `field in (1,2,3)` ?

Comment: fvu – yes like the IN in SQL and i think there is one in python.
markspace – Oh i didn't know List.equals() had this behavior i will try now.
cpp beginner – I know the list in advance.

Comment: No you want Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).contains(foo)

Comment: I don't speak Python, so you're going to have to explain in Java what you want.  If you thought I was referring to Python methods, I wasn't.  That's Java.

Comment: Don't use an array Use a HashSet<String>. Then use its contains() method. Arrays should generally be avoided in Java. Collections are much more powerful (and safe).

Comment: contains shows me an error and equals does nothing, my list is a String[] and i want to know if my string is contained in this list

Comment: Loop through `values` with a for each loop. `for (String i : values)`. Then just  use a `if` statement. `if (i.equals(foo))`. `return true`

Comment: if (Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3").contains(foo)) does not give a compilation error.

Comment: *my list is a String[]*: then it's not a list. It's an array. A List and an array are not the same thing. Use collections, not arrays. Google for "Java collections tutorial".

Comment: Thank you @drewteriyaki, your solution works.
JB Nizet i didn't know about that i will follow a tutorial like you said.

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: The title does not match the question body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare one String with multiple values in one expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205437/compare-one-string-with-multiple-values-in-one-expression)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
String[] values = {"Cheese", "a", "3"};
boolean isIn = false;
for (String str : values) {
   if (str == foo) {
      isIn = true;
      break;
   }
}
```

(Or use str.equals(foo) depending on what you want)

Comment: You do know that using `==` to compare strings in Java is not advisable, and that you should use the `equals` method instead, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the contains() method of List.

```
String values[] = {"Cheese", "a", "3"};
String foo = "a";
String bar = "b";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(values);
System.out.println(list.contains(foo)); // true;
System.out.println(list.contains(bar)); // false;
```

Answer (score 0):

use contains() in List

```
    String[] values = {"Cheese", "a", "3"};
    String foo = "3";
    List<String> valuesAsList = Arrays.asList(values);

    boolean containsFoo = valuesAsList.contains(foo);
    System.out.println("foo contained in list " + containsFoo);
```