# How compare nullable string with multiple values in one expression?

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

Good solution for not `null` string is:

```
Stream.of("REG", "UNREG").anyMatch(str::equals)
```

Taken from here :[Compare one String with multiple values in one expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205437/compare-one-string-with-multiple-values-in-one-expression).

But how modify (or alter) it for nullable string (if the String is `null` return `false`)?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What's wrong with `str != null && Stream.of("REG"...`?

Comment: or `.anyMatch(s -> s.equals(str))` if you're sure the strings in the stream aren't null

Comment: to zapl - thanx!

Comment: Neat Java 10 solution: `Set.of("REG", "UNREG").contains(str)`. Even works with nulls in `str` **or** in the set!

Comment: @DodgyCodeException it’s already in Java 9 and these immutable collections do **not** support `null`, not even `contains(null)`, that’s one of the fundamental differences to other collections.

Comment: @Holger you're right, my proposed "solution" won't work. I keep forgetting that `Set.of` doesn't allow nulls.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to start with `Optional` instead and perform the Stream inside the [`Optional::map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method. If no result is present (str was `null`), then return `false` as requested:

```
Optional.ofNullable(str)
        .map(string -> Stream.of("REG", "UNREG")         // Your Stream as at your snippet
                             .anyMatch(string::equals))  // Returns if the str matches any
        .orElse(false);                                  // Returns false if str is null
```

---

Don't underestimate a simple:

```
str != null && Stream.of("REG", "UNREG").anyMatch(str::equals);
```

In case the first expression is `false` (when `str` is `null`), the second part of the expression will not be evaluated thus never fails on NPE inside of `Stream::anyMatch`.

Comment: Your call to `filter` has no effect and is unnecessary.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException: You are right, the `Optional::map` is applied only if the value is present. I have corrected it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to use [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) + [`List.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

```
Arrays.asList("REG", "UNREG").contains(str)
```

Note that:

1. In both this and your `Stream`-based solution there's a single array allocation.
2. However, such approach makes sense only for regular `equals` (so comparison using e.g. [`equalsIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) is not possible here).

Comment: This differs from the requirement “if the String is `null` return `false`”, as `contains(null)` may return `true` if there is a `null` element. If the requirement allowed returning `true `if `str` is `null` and the `Stream` has a `null` element, `Stream.of(…).anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual​(str))` would be an alternative.

Comment: Well, you took the requirement very literally. I believe the OP did not mean that because such behavior (`null` here and `null` there returning `false`) would be very unintuitive.

Comment: Well yes, I took it very literally (like Nikolas’ answer), but was open to the other possibility. As I said, if matching `null` elements is intended, you can also use `.anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual​(str))` if you already have an existing stream and no way to rewrite the code to produce a collection ala `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: OK, so we made different assumptions regarding where the strings come from. I assumed that the OP looks for an idiom to test for equality with a few `String`s known at compile-time, like `if ("REG".equals(str) || "UNREG".equals(str))` -> `if (Arrays.asList("REG", "UNREG").contains(str))`. Actually, now that I have looked at the [question he referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205437/compare-one-string-with-multiple-values-in-one-expression), it seems that's what he wants. But if he had the `String`s from some other source, your `Stream`-based solution would indeed be much better.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just invert the `equals` clause:

```
boolean contained = Stream.of("REG", "UNREG").anyMatch(s -> s.equals(str));
```

So if `str` is `null` it will not match any of the `String`s in the stream and thus returns `false`.