# How to Compare a String to Two Other Strings All in the Same Line Using .equals()

Tags: java, equals

Let's say I am trying to assign variable hit to true or false depending on whether user input is equal to either "yes" **or** "y" (I have the .toLowerCase() handled). Is there a way I can use .equals in a way that compares one string to **two other** strings all in the same line? I did a bit of searching, but I did not find anything, possibly because of the wording of a question like this.
My line of code:

```
boolean hit = kb.next().toLowerCase.equals("y"); // Change something to see if kb.next() also equals "yes"
```

So, to repeat, the code should see whether string a equals string b **or** string c.
If it is impossible to do this on one line, then just say so in the comments or provide an alternative that is hopefully concise.

Comment: Either use a set of "y" and "yes" and check using contains or assign it to a variable and check using equals.

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205437/compare-one-string-with-multiple-values-in-one-expression

Comment: So the answer is no.

Comment: just curious... why on Earth would you care if it's "on one line" (I assume you mean the code for both checks is written on same line in the source file?) or not ?

Comment: Use regex

    String regex = "y(es)?";
    System.out.println("y".toLowerCase().matches(regex));
    System.out.println("yes".toLowerCase().matches(regex));
    System.out.println("n".toLowerCase().matches(regex));
    System.out.println("no".toLowerCase().matches(regex));

Comment: @62mkv - I would prefer not to create a temp variable to store kb.next() and then compare it to both of them in a separate line.

Comment: you could write 'if (kb.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || kb.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {..} '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `equals` to compare with two strings unless you call it twice, like this:

```java
String input = kb.next().toLowerCase(); 
boolean hit = input.equals("y") || input.equals("yes");
```

You could alternatively use a regex:

```java
boolean hit = input.matches("y(es)?");
```

Or if you don't mind matching the string `"ye"` as well as `"y"` and `"yes"`, you could use `startsWith`:

```java
boolean hit = "yes".startsWith(input);
```

Comment: I chose the third because "ye" can also be interpreted as "yes" in most conversations. Thanks for your help.