# Matcher don't find on 2nd loop

Tags: java, android, regex

1st step is everyth ok, but on 2nd step goes someth wrong: it is very slow (20+ sec) on `find()`. Besides matches() always returs `false`, and I don't know why. Separately every regex works fine. Using Emulator. Thax guys.

```
    String[] regexContent = {"node[\\s\\S]*?(<p>[\\s\\S]+</p>)", 
"([\\s\\S]*?)</div>"};

    Pattern p;
    Matcher m;


        for (String regex : regexContent){ 

            p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            m = p.matcher(result);

            //if (m.matches()) // always false
            result = "";
            if (m.find()) // on 2nd step waits for so long time & don't find
                result = m.group(m.groupCount());
            m.reset();

        }
```

Comment: Slowness is probably related to your pattern.

Comment: Note that `[\\s\\S]` represents white-space or non-white-space character so it means **any character**. You can replace it with dot `.`

Comment: @inquisitor separately patterns works very fast. @Pshemo `result` is array with new lines

Comment: Clear with `String.matches` returns whether the _whole_ string matches the regex, not just any substring

Comment: @inquisitor guess it is someth wrong with my 2nd pattern `([\\s\\S]*?)</div>`. If I use just `.*` it is works fast. Any suggestions? I need get all content before first match `</div>` tag in my string.

Comment: Why are you using an array?  Why not just `"(node[\\s\\S]*?(<p>[\\s\\S]+</p>)) | ([\\s\\S]*?)</div>)"` and then you can dump the `for` loop.

Comment: @inquisitor because the 2nd regex should be match with a result of the 1st one

Comment: Finally decided do not use regex for parsing. From the first it was bad idea to do so)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to reuse the String derived from Matcher.group, better create a new String since what you get from Matcher.group is actually still a substring whose reference pointing to the original one. Thus when you second time read the reference and pass to Pattern.matcher(), you are not actually pass the exact String you get from the first step. Maybe it's a bug or it's designed to work this way. But for your situation, create a new String each time for Matcher.group() always makes life easier. Hope I explained it correctly and completely.

```
String[] regexContent = {"node[\\s\\S]*?(<p>[\\s\\S]+</p>)", 
"([\\s\\S]*?)</div>"};

Pattern p;
Matcher m;


    for (String regex : regexContent){ 

        p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        m = p.matcher(result);

        //if (m.matches()) // always false
        result = "";
        if (m.find()) // on 2nd step waits for so long time & don't find
            result = new String(m.group(m.groupCount()));
        m.reset();

    }
```

Comment: After creating new String it has the same slow effect

Comment: Can you post some testing String you used which leads to the slow effect?

Comment: My 2nd step string is a part of html, someth like that: `<p>text1</p><p>text2</p></div><div><p>text3</p></div>`

Comment: Given the String you provided, IMHO the problem is not caused by the above code. The code has no flaw even you can substitute "[\\s\\S]" with "." and in general this substitution can slightly increase the performance, but not that significantly to your question. Or maybe the String you pass as the "result" is as large as several KB or even MB, then you should consider the substitution as first option to optimize.

Comment: The initial string is a full html page code, it is about 8K & the 1st regex works very fact, the 2nd step `result` even smaller, it is about 4K, and guess the 2nd regex not so hard to do. I don't know.. Previosly I've tryed use Jsoup html parser, as they recommended as very fast, but it is too slow on emulator (about 1-2 min 8K html parsing).

Comment: In the 2n string there is about 10 matches of `([\\s\\S]*?)</div>`. Guess on every regex loop regex processor copy all before each match in a match group. May be it is goes slowly. But I make `.*` non-greedy by adding `?`, and that should work faster, but doesn't.

Comment: Can it be the emulator problem?

Comment: Emulator can be the reason, to make sure of it, maybe you can try to run the app on a real android phone.