# Java regular expression to match specific special characters

Tags: java, regex, string, special-characters

I have input strings containing these special characters in any order: `*` `.` and `\n`

I want to make sure that there are no other characters in the string and `\n` should always be together and not something like `*.*..\..n`, so I want to match the string exactly in Java using a regular expression.

I tried using a regular expression to determine if an input string matches the pattern as below:

```
    String input = "*.*.*.\n..";
    System.out.println(input.matches("[\\\\.*\\n]"));
```

However, the output is false.

I tried using the double escape characters, in order to deal with Java's use of escape characters, but the result isn't as expected.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean your input should only contain literal `*`, `.` and *newline* symbols? Or `*`, `.`, ``\`` and `n`? If you have newlines, then you need something like `input.matches("[.*\n]*")` or `input.matches("[.*\n]+")` (if at least 1 symbol is required in the input).

Comment: @Wiktor Perfect, that worked for me, thanks! Yes, I meant the *newline* symbols. The `input.matches("[.*\n]*")` is what I wanted, as I don't need atleast 1 symbol. For completeness, in Java, it would be `input.matches("[.*\\n]*")`.

Comment: In Java, it is enough to write `input.matches("[.*\n]*")`. Anyway, it has already been posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `*` quantifier to match more than one character. Also, there is no need to escape the literal dot:

```
String input = "*.*.*.\n..";
System.out.println(input.matches("[.*\\n]*"));
```

`[.*\\n]` matches a `.`, or a `*` or the literal newline character `\n`.

Comment: @KirillBulygin `\\n` matches the literal `\n`, exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: I'd better describe it as *`"\\n"` matches a literal newline character*.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the matches method on String does not do what you expect it to do
[Regex doesn't work in String.matches()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923398/regex-doesnt-work-in-string-matches)

You need to you Java's Pattern and Matcher classes.

Answer (score 0):

\s we have to use for a whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]

```
String stringToSearch = "...\n..\n..\n.*.*.*.*...*.*";
System.out.println(stringToSearch.matches("[.*\\s]*"));
```