# Matching three or more identical characters - Java program

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match cases where a sequence of characters contains three or more identical characters in any position, as shown in the following code:

```
class TRY {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String a = "aaaam";
      String b = "aacccccccc";
      String c = "aaffffkb";
      if (b.matches("([a-zA-Z0-9])\\1+"))
          System.out.println("Matches!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

There are many other questions online that suggest using a regular expression like `([a-zA-Z0-9])\\1+` ; `"([a-z\\d])\\1{3,}"` ; or `"([a-z\\d])\\1\\1"`. The `[a-zA-Z0-9]` should match any character, and the `\\1` should reference the matched character. However none of these match any of my strings, and I don't understand why.

Comment: create pattern and use `find`

Comment: `".*([a-zA-Z0-9])\\1{2}.*"`

Comment: what is the expected output of each input?

Comment: The output should just be a yes or no. I also tried with matcher.matches() and it doesn't work. String.matches()  behaves in the same way as Matcher, so I just assumed that the error was in the regex.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew i tried to propose a solution using replaceAll with one of the OP's regex you can check my solution here [ideone](https://ideone.com/J7o2lD) is it a correct one or it is better to use [pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923398/regex-doesnt-work-in-string-matches) like the duplicate question?

Comment: @YCF_L No need for work arounds, `Pattern#find()` is the easiest way.