# To check if a pattern exists in a String

Tags: java, regex

I tried searching but could not find anything that made any sense to me! I am noob at regex :)

Trying to see if a particular word "some_text" exists in another string.

```
String s = "This is a test() function"
String s2 = "This is a test    () function"
```

Assuming the above two strings I can search this using the following pattern at [RegEx Tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output)

```
[^\w]test[ ]*[(]
```

But unable to get a positive match in Java using

```
System.out.println(s.matches("[^\\w]test[ ]*[(]");
```

I have tried with double \ and even four \\ as escape characters but nothing really works.

The requirement is to see the word starts with space or is the first word of a line and has an open bracket "(" after that particular word, so that all these "test (), test() or test    ()" should get a positive match.

Using Java 1.8

Cheers,
Faisal.

Comment: Should `test() function` also match?

Comment: Yup it should :)

Comment: Use `find()` instead of `matches()`

Comment: Why are you using `[]` for single characters?

Comment: Perhaps this page can be helpful [Regex doesn't work in String.matches()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923398/regex-doesnt-work-in-string-matches)

Comment: If you want to use `.matches` try `.*(?<!\\S)test\\h*\\(.*` to match the whole line asserting a non whitespace char before test like `System.out.println(s.matches(".*(?<!\\S)test\\h*\\(.*"));`  See https://ideone.com/07Fpjm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point you are missing is that Java `matches()` puts a `^` at the start and a `$` at the end of the Regex for you. So your expression actually is seen as:

```
^[^\w]test[ ]*[(]$
```

which is never going to match your input.

Going from your requirement description, I suggest reworking your regex expression to something like this (assuming by "particular word" you meant `test`):

```
(?:.*)(?<=\s)(test(?:\s+)?\()(?:.*)
```

[See the regex at work here.](https://regex101.com/r/XvHHfR/1)

Explanation:

```
^                 Start of line - added by matches()
(?:.*)            Non-capturing group - match anything before the word, but dont capture into a group
(?<=\s)           Positive lookbehind - match if word preceded by space, but dont match the space
(                 Capturing group $1
  test(?:\s+)?    Match word test and any following spaces, if they exist
  \(              Match opening bracket
)                 
(?:.*)            Non-capturing group - match rest of string, but dont capture in group
$                 End of line - added by matches()
```

Code sample:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "This is a test() function";
        String s2 = "This is a test    () function";
        System.out.println(s.matches("(?:.*)((?<=\\s))(test(?:\\s+)?\\()(?:.*)")); 
        //true
    }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation! makes perfect sense now! Thanks vs97 :)

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers! But this was simpler as I don't need to go through two more class objects to get what I wanted.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The `Matches()` method tells whether or not this **whole** string matches the given regular expression. Since that's not the case you'll yield errors.

If you just interested in *if* your lookup-value exists within the string I found the following usefull:

---

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "This is a test    () function";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\btest *\\(");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find())
      System.out.println("Found a match");
    else
      System.out.println("Did not find a match");
  }
}
```

---

I went with the following pattern: `\\btest *\\(`

- `\\b` - Match word-boundary (will also catch if first word).
- `test` - Literally match your lookup-value.
- `*` - Zero or more literal spaces.
- `\\(` - Escaped open paranthesis to match literally.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xg8iOhm6xul2Av_i)

Comment: Tried: System.out.println(s.matches("\\btest\\b\\s*\\(")); but still returns false :(

Comment: @Faisal, I'm no Java expert but pieced something together that worked for me. It may be helpfull.

Comment: @JvdV Not my DV but you could make a note why the code of the OP does not work.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, thanks for the feedback. I have edited a little.

Comment: Thank you, guys! You are the best!!! Indeed "matches()" however, adds a "^" at the beginning of the string and assumes that it is the start of the string and matches it as a whole which of course does not work for me. find() works great, just tested it

Comment: I wish I could accept this as the answer as well but I ended up accepting @vs97's solution as it made more sense to me that I don't have to add two more classes to my code! Thank you once again for this quick solution, this made my day much better and I learned quite a few new things about the crazy regex :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should be enough:

```
s.find("\\btest\\s*\\(")
```

Comment: this will match "textexttest()" as well, but it should not

Comment: I did not downwoted you. I was somebody else

Comment: Sometimes you wonder why people downvote.... I think it's helpfull so there you go

Answer (score 2):

Try this "\btest\b(?= *()".

And dont use "matches", use "find". Mathes trying to match the whole string

https://regex101.com/r/xaPCyp/1

Answer (score 1):

The `.matches` method will match the whole string where your pattern would only get a partial match.

In the pattern that you tried, the negated character class `[^\\w]` could also match more than a whitespace boundary as it matches any char except a word character. It could for example also match a `(` or a newline.

As per the comments `test() function` should also match, using `[^\\w]` or `(?<=\s)` expects a character to be there on the left.

---

Instead you could make use of `(?<!\\S)` to assert a whitespace boundary on the left.

```
.*(?<!\S)test\h*\(.*
```

**Explanation**

- `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary on the left
- `test\h*` Match `test` and 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\(` Match a `(` char
- `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dPTdog/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/07Fpjm)

In Java

```
System.out.println(s.matches(".*(?<!\\S)test\\h*\\(.*"));
```