# regular expression to find sub string from a string having no white space

Tags: java, regex

I have sample string as below :

input - `{"page":1,"per_page":10,"total":76,"total_pages":8,"data":""}`

I want to filter out the `total_pages` as `8` in a sample Java program.
For that I thought to build a regex to filter out substring as `"total_pages":8,`

Below is code .

```
**String regex = "/(.*total_pages.*?,/)";
String res =  "{\"(page\":1,\"per_page\":10,\"total\":76,\"total_pages\":8,\"data\":)";
System.out.println(res);
System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regex,res));**
```

Please tell why It never matches with the substring.

Comment: I also tried using other regex as : "(.*total_pages.*?,)" , ".*total_pages.*?," , ".*total_pages.*"   but nothing get matched .

Comment: Use `Matcher.find()` with `String regex= "\"total_pages\":(\\d+)"` and then use `if (m.find()) { System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); }` , see the [code example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)

Comment: It works fine using Matcher  but I am unable to understand why Pattern.matches() does not retrun true if any parts getting matched. Is Pattern.matches() looks for complete string to be matched with the pattern ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923398/regex-doesnt-work-in-string-matches