# String.matches() returning false

Tags: regex, string

if we are saying .matches() tries to match entire input string then why following returns false?

```
String input = "HOLIDAY"; String pattern = "H*I*Y";

input.matches(pattern) --> returns false;
```

Note: I have already looked at [Regex doesn't work in String.matches()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923398/regex-doesnt-work-in-string-matches/70099545#70099545)

Comment: `H*` means "letter `H`, repeated zero or more times", see Regex101.com (remember to choose appropriate regex flavor for your programming language). It's not wildcard like in globs. You probably want `H.*|.*Y`.

Comment: `String pattern = "H\*I\*Y"` produces a compile error, so it won't "return" anything. What did you actually code?

Comment: @Bohemian I meant H * I * Y only but have put \ for stackoverflow editor escape! Else it was showing! Have edited now!
H*I*Y

Comment: @yeputons thanks for explaining got it now!! But then why It works fine when we use pattern compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is not globbing!

Your regex `"H*I*Y"` does not mean "`H` then anything then `I` then anything then *Y*"; it means "any number of `H` (including none) followed by any number of `I` (including none) followed by a `Y`".

The regex equivalent of globbing's `*` is `.*`: the dot means "any character" an `*` means "any number of (including none)".

Try:

```
String pattern = "H.*I.*Y";
```