# Regex validates fine with online tool, but not in java application

Tags: java, regex, validation, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

I have this regex used in Java as shown below:

```
private static final String DATE_TIME_REGEX = "^(20[1-5]\\d)-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12]\\d|3[01])\\s([0-1]\\d)|(2[0-3]):([0-5]\\d):([0-5]\\d)$";

public static boolean validateDate(String dateStr) {
    return dateStr.matches(DATE_TIME_REGEX);
}
```

...to validate a date in this format:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    String formattedDate = dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now());
```

...using this online tool

https://regexr.com/

...where adding this regex:

```
^(20[1-5]\d)-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s([0-1]\d)|(2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)$
```

...works fine to validate a date string like:

```
2022-11-02 00:00:00
```

... but fails to validate (with no indication of the specifics) using the aforementioned validation code in java

To rule out the only caveat I can think of - when adding the code from the online tool into the java code, I have to add an extra \ before the other backslashes in the regex pattern when moving it from the online tool, i.e. `\d and \s  ->  \\d and \\s`.
However, am highly dubious as to whether that is the issue

Comment: Here it doesn't match if I select Java: https://regex101.com/r/Dsp7TD/1

Comment: :( it needs to remove the double escaping

Comment: I also Like this site because it shows a visual representation of the Regex, if you know regex it becomes easier to debug it: https://www.debuggex.com/r/HBrpD2e_t-L9VUqe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern contains one group and alternation that look to be out of place:

```
^(20[1-5]\d)-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s([0-1]\d)|(2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):...
                                                      ^ HERE > ^
```

This makes your [current pattern match](https://regex101.com/r/FC3NGk/3) <sup>regex101</sup>

- EITHER the left part of the alternation from *start* up to the `[0-1]\d` hours-part
- OR the right part from the `2[0-3]` hours-part until the *end*

Using this with [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) cannot work because it gets matched [against the full string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923398/regex-doesnt-work-in-string-matches):

> `public boolean matches()`
> Attempts to **match the entire region** against the pattern.
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained...

---

Refactored by fixing the structure it works fine (using `matches`, the `^` and `$` are *redundant*).

```
20[1-5]\d-(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d
```

[See this Java demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##bU/LbsMgELzzFSufTCMQEPXQRGk@IrlhDtSmDq5fMiRp1eTb3bXrVj0UIWaZ2VmGyl4sq4q3cfRN3w0RKiS47/jDlpC8tiHA0YVIPgkA9OeX2ucQoo0Il84X0Fjfpoc4@LYEO5RBGzp1zu24Xn1ra1h0BNhB664LkSZKKMWkZEKBEJt5J3T7n3dwpXtHN1q0ZI8mywqW7jdij7cnc5NaSGXoX0ojgV23NUqGZllATQsmZ1JhtTZ0IuZZv0Xy8/oCh48QXcO7c@Q9BonTX2EFCeye8VhN8XhjY35yIZ0z0u/8d3Ifxy8) or a [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FavfIT/3) (pattern explained and code generator)