# Regular expression to group a pattern OR group empty string as ""

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.3.2 with regular expressions. I have a pretty simple function

```
def DoRegexThings(somestring):
    m = re.match(r'(^\d+)( .*$)?', somestring)
    return m.group(1)
```

Which I am using to just get a numeric portion at the beginning of string, and discard the rest. However, it fails on the case of an empty string, since it is unable to match a group.

I've looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333461/regular-expression-which-matches-a-pattern-or-is-an-empty-string) which was asked previously, and changed my regular expression to this:

```
(^$)|(^\d+)( .*$)?
```

But it only causes it to return `"None"` every time, and still fails on empty strings. What I really want is a regular expression which I can use to either grab the numeric portion of my record, e.g. if the record is `1234 sometext`, I just want `1234`, or if the string is empty I want `m.group(1)` to return an empty string. My workaround right now is

```
m = re.match(r'(^\d+)( .*$)?', somestring)
if m == None: # Handle empty string case
    return somestring
else:
    return m.group(1)
```

But if I can avoid checking the match object for `None`, I'd like to. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: `(^$)|(^\d+)( .*$)?` will "work", even for empty strings, but of course the number (if matched) will now be in group 2 instead of group 1 because you've added another capturing group (that will match the empty string) before it.

Comment: Also, *if* you need to compare to `None`, use `if m is None:` instead of `if m == None:`, but in this case, `if not m:` would be the preferred solution - which you don't need, however (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this overly complicated:

```
re.match(r"\d*", somestring).group()
```

will return a number if it's at the start of the string (`.match()` ensures this) or the empty string if there is no number.

```
>>> import re
>>> somestring = "987kjh"
>>> re.match(r"\d*", somestring).group()
'987'
>>> somestring = "kjh"
>>> re.match(r"\d*", somestring).group()
''
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, and so much better than the way I was going about it. Thank you!