# Regex string does not start or end (or both) with forward slash

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression for javascript that should return a match when the string does not start or end with a forward slash (or both). The problem is that it does not return a match if I just type a single character (i.e. 'g').

https://regex101.com/r/9Bi3uc/1

The expression: `(^[^/].*)(.*[^/]$)`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use `^(?!/)|$(?<!/)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew maybe `^(?!\/).*$(?<!\/)`?  https://regex101.com/r/9Bi3uc/2

Comment: @MaximShoustin OP says "not start or end or both", not "both"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason it won't match single characters, is that you have two instances of `[^/]` in your regex. This means that it needs at least two characters that are not slashes for it to properly match. A quick solution to this is to use a regex OR operator to handle this case. Here's a modified version of your regex that matches all of your examples:

`((^[^/].*[^/]$)|^[^/]$)`

This can be broken into two segments

`(^[^/].*[^/]$)`

this first part is a shortened version of yours and will capture any strings with a length of 2 or more that don't start or end with a slash.

The second part on the other side of the OR operator (`|`) is this
`^[^/]$`

This will match a single character lines that are not a slash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^[^\/](?:.*[^\/])?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1tCEJI/1). If you need to also allow empty strings, you need to [wrap the pattern with an optional non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23255633/3832970):

```
^(?:[^\/](?:.*[^\/])?)?$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1tCEJI/2).

Note that [`.` does not always match any chars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/3832970), make sure you use the right flag for the `.` to match line breaks as well, or use workarounds.

If you have a specific pattern to validate specific strings and you want to **add the restrictions rgarding leading/trailing `/` chars**, you can use lookarounds:

```
^(?!\/)your_pattern$(?<!\/)
```

This will match your pattern as a whole string while not allowing `/` char at the start, end or both.

Another note on `/` escaping:

- In JavaScript regex,  in character classes, you do not need to escape `/`: `/[/]/` is valid
- In string regex patterns, when you define the regex via a string literal, you do not need to escape `/`s (`new RegExp("a/b/c"))`
- You can avoid escaping `/`s in case you can use another regex delimiter char (e.g. in PHP, `"~a/b/c~"`)