# Regex to validate email is failing if 2 "@" are provided

Tags: c, regex

We have followed the regex for validating RFC 2822 standard.

The function is as follows:

```
int isValidEmail(const char *email_id)
{
    /* Regular expression to validate email */
    const char *reg_exp =
        "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+(\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$";

    regex_t preg;

    /* Compile the regular expression */
    if (regcomp(&preg, reg_exp, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NOSUB|REG_ICASE) != 0)
        return FAILURE;

    /* Execute the regex, 0 for success */
    if (regexec(&preg, email_id, (size_t)0, NULL, 0) != 0)
        return FAILURE;

    regfree(&preg);

    return SUCCESS;

}
```

But if I provide emails like "test@test@test.com", the emails are getting accepted.

Is there any problem with this regex?

Appreciate the help in advance.

Thanks,
Mathew Liju

Comment: The string `test@test@test.com` contains the valid email id `test@test.com` - could that be the reason?

Comment: related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard

Comment: I found this Regular expression **^[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,})$** (source: http://www.markussipila.info/pub/emailvalidator.php)

Comment: Note that `"foo@bar"@example.com` is a valid address.

Comment: @Gumbo May be it is valid as per the RFC, and OP is indeed talking about RFC; but do any email service provider allow characters other than `[\w.-]` in the email id? I guess my question is, is it really worth validating email ids using the rfc when most of the users have providers who allow only _decent_ email ids?

Comment: @Amarghosh You should not assume people to be decent. :)

Comment: Thank you every one, adding a "^" in the regex solved my problem. Also, our code is expected to support RFC, so went for this regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a `^` at the beginning of the regex. It matches the beginning of line. Without `^` regex will match the substring `test@test.com` as it is a valid email id matching the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your first character class contains the sequence `+-/`, which is treated as a range.  In addition to those three characters, the range will match a period or a comma, which I'm pretty sure you don't want.  You should move the hyphen to the end of the class, like it is in all the other classes.

That's the only structural problem I see with the regex.  As for whether it's the *right* regex for an email address, well, there's no such thing.  There are huge variations depending on the context and what you're doing with the regex.  When it comes to email-address regexes, you're *always* flying seat-of-the-pants. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a start anchor `^` as:

```
"^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+(\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$";
```