# Valid domain name

Tags: php, regex, validation, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

I'm building a small app in PHP, and have to validate domain names (for use in E-mail addresses). For instance if I have mads@gmail.com I want to check if gmail.com is a valid domain name (I'm essentially throwing away the part before the @).

I have been using the following code:

```
if (!preg_match ("/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]+[a-z0-9](\.[a-z]{2,4})+$/i", trim($valid_emails[$i]))) {
         // Return error
}
```

And everything has been working fine. Until I got GE MoneyBank as a client. They are using ge.com as their domain, and that doesn't pass.

I have a rudimentary understanding of regex, and have tried deleting some of the [a-z0-9] blocks so the minimum character count comes down to 2, but without luck. Can anyone with more experience point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It won't handle `.museum` TLDs either.

Comment: dupe?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses

Comment: @David Dorward, My answer should support all known TLDs.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate at all - the other post states that the function is overkill and validates a whole URL, not just the domain and tld.  for somebody who doesn't understand regular expressions, I think this could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you currently have does the following:
 - `[a-z0-9]`: A letter or a number
 - `[a-z0-9\-]+`: A letter or a number or a hyphen, 1 or more times
 - `[a-z0-9]`: A letter or a number

Your problem is that it is expecting at least 3 letters.

You need to make sure it can accept only two letters, and the last one can't be a hyphen.

So you need to change the middle expression to 0 or more times:
 - `[a-z0-9\-]*`: A letter or a number or a hyphen, 0 or more times

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It still says “ge.com” is invalid.

Comment: works on my end.  you can try it in here: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php