# Email validator regex

Tags: java, regex, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regexp recognition of email address hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard)

Hi,

I would like to implement validator for only local part of the email address.

Any suggestions please welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regexp recognition of email address hard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard) Although this question specifically states the *local part* is of interest, the answer will most likely be found in any other email+regex question that has already been asked.

Comment: @Aron Rotteveel. @Thomman only wants to validate the *local part* of the email address

Comment: @Raghuram: which is *exactly* what I explained in the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Email address article at wikipedia (Syntax section)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax):

> The local-part of the email address may use any of these ASCII characters:
>
> - Uppercase and lowercase English letters (a–z, A–Z)
> - Digits 0 to 9
> - Characters ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ ` { | } ~
> - Character . (dot, period, full stop) provided that it is not the first or last character, and provided also that it does not appear two or more times consecutively (e.g. John..Doe@example.com).

The syntax is formally defined in RFC 5322 [section 3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) and RFC 5321. It is defined by a grammar in which the local part starts like this:

> ```
> local-part      =   dot-atom / quoted-string / obs-local-part
> atext           =   ALPHA / DIGIT /    ; Printable US-ASCII
>                    "!" / "#" /        ;  characters not including
>                    "$" / "%" /        ;  specials.  Used for atoms.
>                    "&" / "'" /
>                    "*" / "+" /
>                    "-" / "/" /
>                    "=" / "?" /
>                    "^" / "_" /
>                    "`" / "{" /
>                    "|" / "}" /
>                    "~"
>
> atom            =   [CFWS] 1*atext [CFWS]
>
> dot-atom-text   =   1*atext *("." 1*atext)
>
> dot-atom        =   [CFWS] dot-atom-text [CFWS]
>
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following link. This is the best reference I found:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html