# Validate an emailAddressfield in blackberry

Tags: java, email, blackberry

How can i validate an emailAddressfield in blackberry?

Thanks in advance, I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validating EMail addresses (format wise) is *very* hard, so hard, that one may consider to just don't do it. The recommendation is, at least, to not do it yourself but try to get a library for that task.

[Here's a good article on SO about this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard)

Comment: hello frens,,,,thanks for replyin ...
i got the solution using this......

public boolean isDataValid(String mail) {
    //  String address = getText();
      int at = mail.indexOf("@");
      int len = mail.length();
      if (at <= 0 || at > len - 6) 
       return false;
      String host = mail.substring(at + 1, len);
      len = host.length();
      if (host.indexOf("..") >= 0) 
       return false;
      int dot = host.indexOf(".");
      return (dot > 0 && dot <= len - 3);
    }

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about Java Microedition basic validation is possible through [TextField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextField.html) constrain parameter as TextField.EMAILADDR

Example `TextField("Email", "", 100, TextField.EMAILADDR)`
However I would be wary of this as does check only for basic stuff