# Count characters after given symbol in oracle varchar column value

Tags: oracle, string-length

How would I go about counting the characters after a certain character. I'm new to Oracle, and I've learned quite a bit however I'm stumped at this point. I found a couple functions that will get you a substring and I found a function that will give you the length of a string. I am examining an email address, myemail@thedomain.com. I want to check the length after the '.' in the email.

```
SELECT email
FROM user_table
WHERE length(substr(email, /*what values*/, /*to put here*/))
```

I don't know if it's actually possible to find the location of the final '.' in the email string?

Comment: after the '.' or after the '@'?

Comment: I apologize, I want to count after the '.'

Comment: ok, actually I'm wondering whether you're checking for the length for some of your own reasons, or you're actually checking the email validity?

Comment: I'm checking to confirm the TLD (top level domain) is 3 characters and under.

Comment: Bad idea, they could be up to 6 characters :-)

Comment: Haha I know they can be that long, e.g. .museum, but I want to make sure everything is 4 or under (:

Comment: @Trim, as I just commented under Sebas' answer do not use regular expressions to validate e-mail addresses. On top of the answers in those questions non-latin TLDs now exist and anyone can make up their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I would use `substr`.  You can try something like this :

```
select length('abcd@efgh.123.4567') - instr('abcd@efgh.123.4567', '.', -1) from dual
```

Using `instr(..,..,-1)` searches backwards from the last character to find the position.

Comment: This works until email addresses such as my.email@thedomain.com appear. It only looks at the first '.', not the final one. Any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing checks, I suggest you validate the format with regular expressions using [REGEXP_INSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm). For instance, an email validation I found on this site is `REGEXP_INSTR(email, '\w+@\w+(\.\w+)+') > 0`

I didn't check it myself, but it looks quite ok.

Cheers.

Comment: I might have upvoted for the regexes. However, I cannot up-vote anyone who suggests using a [regular expression to validate an e-mail address](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html); it is [technically impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard).

Comment: I know, I never recommended that! The user wants to do some checks, I'm just helping him doing his checks... :-)